# Stopping columns resizable in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

How I can make all the columns of jqgrid not resizable? Currently I think every column I've to specify the property { resizable:false }. Is there anyway I can specify for the entire grid?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Starting with version 3.8.2 jqGrid supports one very useful feature: **column templates**. (It's probably not quite correct from me to praise the feature because the feature was introduced on [my own suggestion](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/templates-for-columns-in-colmodel/#p20807) :-)). The feature is still not really documented, but it can be used very easily.

I explain it on an example. If you define additional jqGrid parameter

```
cmTemplate:{resizable:false}
```

then your problem will be solved.

If you have more properties which are common in **all columns** of `colModel` items, for example `align:'center'` the `cmTemplate` will help you also (cmTemplate:{resizable:false, align:'center'}). In jqGrid 3.8.2 was small [bug](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/wrong-priority-in-colmodel-template-and-colmodel-properties/) in priority of template settings relatively to settings from `colModel`, but the bug is fixed in jqGrid 4.0.0. So the properties from `cmTemplate` can be interpret just as **default values for `colModel` items**.

One more version of usage jqGrid column template is in the form:

```
var myDateTemplate = {sorttype:'date', formatter:'date',
                      formatoptions: {newformat:'m/d/Y'}, datefmt: 'm/d/Y',
                      align:'center', width:80 }
$("list").jqGrid({
    colModel: [
        ...
        {name:'column1': template:myDateTemplate},
        {name:'column2': template:myDateTemplate, width:90},
        ...
    ]
    ...
});
```

In the way you can define some templates (like `myDateTemplate`) and use there in many places in your grid (or gids). With respect of the feature you can make your code shorter, better readable and easily changeable.

Comment: You are really great in jqgrid. I'll give a try and see how things work, before that I'll upgrade jqgrid from 3.8.2 to 4.0.

Comment: I can't able to upgrade successfully :( facing many issues here and there. Is there any way we can do this in 3.8.2?

Comment: @Vijaya Anand: I wrote in my answer that column templates are suported already in jqGrid 3.8.2. So you can just add `cmTemplate:{resizable:false}` parameter in your current grid an your problem should be solved.

Comment: @Vijaya Anand: Do you have any success in the usage of the column templates?

Comment: @Oleg: There is formatter twice in Date template sample:  `formatter:'date', formatter:'date'`

Answer (score 0):

Template works great for me:

```
 { name: 'quantity_warehouse', index: 'quantity_warehouse', template: intColTemplate, width: '70' },

 { name: 'status', index: 'status', align: 'left', template: stringColTemplate, width: '90' },

 { name: 'snapshot_at', index: 'snapshot_at', template: dateColTemplate },

 { name: 'applied_at', index: 'applied_at', template: dateColTemplate },
```

JS:

```
var dateColTemplate = { align: 'left', search: true, stype: 'text', width: '70', datefmt: 'm/d/y', formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'm/d/y', newformat: 'm/d/Y' }, sorttype: 'date', searchrules: { required: true, date: true }, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ge', 'le'],

    dataInit: function (el) {
        $(el).datepicker({ changeYear: true, changeMonth: true, showButtonPanel: true });
    }
}
};
var intColTemplate = { align: 'left', search: true, stype: 'text', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ge', 'le']} };
var stringColTemplate = { align: 'left', search: true, stype: 'text', searchoptions: { sopt: ['bw', 'cn']} };
```