# Get all the edited rows in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

How to get all the rows that are edited ?

I have following `jqgird`, where the users can edit the check boxes of all the records.
When the Save button is clicked, I need to know what are all the records edited, I am a new to `jquery` and `jqgrid`.

Can anyone help me ?

Here is the jqgrid and html using :

```
var customerCodesView       = {};
customerCodesView.customerCodesView = function() {

$jq("#customerCodesTable").jqGrid(
        {   
            colNames : ['Cust #','Customer Name', '1', '2','3', '4', '5', '6','7', '8','9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '-1'],

            colModel : [{name : 'customerNumber',index : 'baseCustomerNumber',width : 55, align :'center'},
                        {name : 'customerName',index : 'storeName',width : 100, sorttype :'text', align :'center'},
                        {name : 'creditCodesPermissions.1',index : 'codeOne',width : 40,align : "center", editable:true, edittype:'checkbox', editoptions: { value:"True:False"}, formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: {disabled : false}},
                         {name : 'creditCodesPermissions.2',index : 'codeTwo',width : 40,align : "center", editable:true, edittype:'checkbox', editoptions: { value:"True:False"}, formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: {disabled : false}},
                         {name : 'creditCodesPermissions.3',index : 'codeThree',width : 40,align : "center", editable:true, edittype:'checkbox', editoptions: { value:"True:False"}, formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: {disabled : false}},
                         {name : 'creditCodesPermissions.4',index : 'codeFour',width : 40,align : "center", editable:true, edittype:'checkbox', editoptions: { value:"True:False"}, formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: {disabled : false}},
                         {name : 'creditCodesPermissions.5',index : 'codeFive',width : 40,align : "center", editable:true, edittype:'checkbox', editoptions: { value:"True:False"}, formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: {disabled : false}},
                         {name : 'creditCodesPermissions.6',index : 'codeSix',width : 40,align : "center", editable:true, edittype:'checkbox', editoptions: { value:"True:False"}, formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: {disabled : false}},
                         {name : 'creditCodesPermissions.7',index : 'codeSeven',width : 40,align : "center", editable:true, edittype:'checkbox', editoptions: { value:"True:False"}, formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: {disabled : false}},
                         {name : 'creditCodesPermissions.8',index : 'codeEight',width : 40,align : "center", editable:true, edittype:'checkbox', editoptions: { value:"True:False"}, formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: {disabled : false}},
                         {name : 'creditCodesPermissions.9',index : 'codeNine',width : 40,align : "center", editable:true, edittype:'checkbox', editoptions: { value:"True:False"}, formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: {disabled : false}},
                         {name : 'creditCodesPermissions.10',index : 'codeTen',width : 40,align : "center", editable:true, edittype:'checkbox', editoptions: { value:"True:False"}, formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: {disabled : false}},
                         {name : 'creditCodesPermissions.11',index : 'codeEleven',width : 40,align : "center", editable:true, edittype:'checkbox', editoptions: { value:"True:False"}, formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: {disabled : false}},
                         {name : 'creditCodesPermissions.12',index : 'codeTwelve',width : 40,align : "center", editable:true, edittype:'checkbox', editoptions: { value:"True:False"}, formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: {disabled : false}},
                         {name : 'creditCodesPermissions.13',index : 'codeThirteen',width : 40,align : "center", editable:true, edittype:'checkbox', editoptions: { value:"True:False"}, formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: {disabled : false}},
                         {name : 'creditCodesPermissions.-1',index : 'codeMinusOne',width : 40,align : "center", editable:true, edittype:'checkbox', editoptions: { value:"True:False"}, formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: {disabled : false}}
                       ],

            pager : '#customerCodesTablePager',
            rowNum : 1000,
            loadOnce:true,
            sortorder : "desc",
            viewrecords : true,
            gridview : true,
            autowidth : true,
            multiselect : true,
            jsonReader : {
                repeatitems : false,
                root : function(obj) {
                    return obj;
                },
                page : function(obj) {
                    return 1;
                },
                total : function(obj) {
                    return 1;
                },
                records : function(obj) {
                    return obj.length;
                }
            },
            sortable : true,
            caption : "Credit Codes"
        });

$jq("form#customerCodesForm").submit(
                function() {
                    var newUrl = resourceURL+"&action=searchCreditCodes&"+ $jq(this).serialize();
                    $jq("#customerCodesTable").jqGrid("setGridParam", {"url" : newUrl,datatype : "json"}).trigger("reloadGrid");
                    return false;
                });

$jq(".submit").button( {
    icons : {
        primary : 'ui-icon-circle-zoomin'
    }
});

$jq("#customerCodesTableSave").click(function() {

    var id = $jq("#customerCodesTable").jqGrid('getGridParam','selarrow');
    alert("save");
    if (id) {
        var rowdata = $jq("#customerCodesTable").jqGrid('getRowData', id);
        var postData = JSON.stringify(rowdata);

        alert("postdata"+postData);
    }
    saveGrid();

});


function saveGrid() {
    alert("saveGrid");
    var saveCollection = [];
    //Collect all rows in editmode, the rows to be saved.
    $.each($jq("#customerCodesTable").getDataIDs(), function (index, id) {
        var row = grid.getInd(id, true);
        if (row !== false) {
            if ($(row).attr('editable') === '1') {
                saveCollection.push(id);
            }
        }
    });
    alert(""+saveCollection.toString() + "length" + saveCollection.length );
}

};
```

HTML :

```
<div id="customerCodes_Form">
  <form class="customerCodesForm" id="customerCodesForm" method="post">
    <fieldset class="ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        <legend class="ui-widget ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">Permissions by Customer</legend>
        <div>
            <span>
                <label for="customerNumber">Customer Number</label>
                <input id="customerNumber" name="customerNumber" class=""/>
            </span>
            <button class="submit" type="submit">Search</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
<div id="customerCodesGrid">
    <table id="customerCodesTable"><tbody><tr><td></td></tr></tbody></table>
    <div id="customerCodesTablePager"></div>
    <div style="float:right;">
        <button id="customerCodesTableSave">Save</button>
        <button id="customerCodesTableCancel">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Updated :  @Justin Thank you for your input, I am new to JQuery but it is always good to get the things correct :) The data in the jqGrid is not filled at the first time, it will be empty. There is a search input box to enter the customer number, after the user hit "Go" button I am making an ajax call to fill up json data in jqgrid, the data looks like this `[{"customerNumber":"64093","customerName":"#9735 WATSONTOWN BILO         ","creditCodesPermissions.1":"True","creditCodesPermissions.2":"True","creditCodesPermissions.3":"False","creditCodesPermissions.4":"True","creditCodesPermissions.5":"True","creditCodesPermissions.6":"True","creditCodesPermissions.7":"True","creditCodesPermissions.8":"True","creditCodesPermissions.9":"False","creditCodesPermissions.10":"False","creditCodesPermissions.11":"True","creditCodesPermissions.12":"True","creditCodesPermissions.13":"True","creditCodesPermissions.-1":"True"}]`, I am not sure how to use jsonmap for this kind of output, I will try to figure it out. I will try "celledit" option that you mentioned. Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear from the code which you posted how you fill the grid contain. You don't define any `datatype`, so the default value `datatype: 'xml'` will be used and the jqGrid will try to load XML data per ajax from the `url` which you also not defined and the default `url: ""` will be used. So the jqGrid will try to load from your server the XML data. I am not sure that it's want you wanted. Because you use `jsonReader` you plan probably to use `datatype: 'json'`. If you would include the test input data in your question it would clear many things.

The next problem. You use special characters in the 'name' property of the `colModel` (`'creditCodesPermissions.7'` or even `'creditCodesPermissions.-1'`) which is not permitted. Depend on how you plan to fill the data you can use `jsonpmap` or `xmlmap` having the points, but you should do this only if it is really required and you can't change the format of XML/JSON data. In any way you will need to change the of the 'name' property of the `colModel` to values like `'creditCodesPermissions7'`. You should use no meta-characters (such as !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~) as a literal part of a name because the names will be used to construct the ids of some grid elements.

Additionally I would recommend you to use [column templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044047/stopping-columns-resizable-in-jqgrid/6047856#6047856). You should just define an object like

```
var myCheckBoxTemplate = {
    width: 40, align: "center", editable: true, edittype: 'checkbox',
    editoptions: { value: "True:False"}, formatter: "checkbox",
    formatoptions: {disabled : false}
};
```

then the definition of the columns inside of `colModel` could be like

```
{name: 'creditCodesPermissions1', index: 'codeOne', template: myCheckBoxTemplate}
```

It would simplify your jqGrid.

One more small remark: there are no `loadOnce:true` parameter. Only `loadonce:true`. The `loadOnce:true` parameter will be just ignored.

To answer on your main question one need to understand first how the grid data are filled. In any way I would you recommend you use any from three standard editing mode: inline editing, cell editing of the form editing. In your case the inline editing or [cell editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:cell_editing) would be probably better. In case of the usage of the [cell editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:cell_editing) the `"dirty-cell"` class will be added to the cell element (`<td>` element) and `"edited"` class will be added to the grid row (`<tr>` element). So you can use the fact to detect which cells from which rows are changed by the user.

Comment: I did change the jqgrid colModel to use json-map, it worked fine.