# JqGrid: Remove tooltip for all rows & columns

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid table with many columns. I dont want to use the `setCell` method for every column to disable tooltip. Is there any way to disable tool tips for all the columns and rows in one shot with out looping through each column?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you use `title: false` in the `colModel` no `title` attribute will be created for the cells of the grid on the corresponding column. So no tooltips will be shown no the hovering of cells. To set `title: false` as your *default* setting for `colModel` you can use `cmTemplate`:

```
cmTemplate: { title: false }
```

See [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044047/stopping-columns-resizable-in-jqgrid/6047856#6047856) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

you can use title attribute for each column to hide the title tool tip for specific column   as shown below :

```
{ name: 'Export To Excel ', index: 'exporttoexcel', sortable: false, editable: true,title:false, search: false,formatter: AppendCheckBox ,width:30},
```