# jqgrid oversmart and applying title to my td's

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am using this function of jqgrid:

```
 tableToGrid("#something", { width: '400', height: 'auto', caption: ''});
```

This works fine but when I hover over something, it shows the same text as seen in cell. I don't really want this. When I did viewsource in Firefox, jqgrid added title attribute to all my td's. How can I stop this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `tableToGrid`, so it's more difficult for you to find the correct parameter in the documentation. [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660475/jqgrid-remove-tooltip-for-all-rows-columns/7660674#7660674) shows the way to solve your problem. In case of usage of [tableToGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:table_to_jqgrid) it will look as following:

```
tableToGrid("#something", {width: '400', height: 'auto', cmTemplate: {title: false}});
```