# Annoying tooltip above jqGrid cells - see screenshot

Tags: javascript, css, jqgrid

On one of the columns of my jqGrid, I transfer digits from the backend, and then using the loadComplete event, and a lookup table, I convert those digits into the appropriate string representation, the problem is, that after the conversion is done, once the user places the mouse pointer above one of those converted cells, an annoying tooltip with the digit still appears.

How can I solve this?.

Screen-shot:
[image]

code:

```
    loadComplete: function(){
          $('td[aria-describedby="list2_relevancy"]').each(function(){
              var rowId = $(this).siblings().filter('[aria-describedby="list2_id"]').html();
              var statusId = $(this).html();
              var innerHTML = typeof lookup[statusId] === 'undefined' ? get_phrase("New") : lookup[statusId];
              $(this).html('<span style="cursor:pointer;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;" onclick="showApproveList(' + rowId + ')">' + innerHTML + '</span>');
          });
```

How can I solve this?.

Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: Please include the screenshot in your post, so that we can properly help you.

Comment: The screen shot is already there, only the part of the grid though, because I don't see how my desktop and browser are relevant.
Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Sorry, the page wasn't rendered correctly last time. I reckon that the number '1' is the rowId. I have experienced this in the past so that what gave me the idea. Please reply so that I can assist you further!

Comment: It is not the Row id sir, it is the value that was previously in the cell that I place the mouse over, prior to adding the code above to the loadComplete()  event.

Comment: Roger that, more perusing, do you have a 'title' property on your column? If no, can you kindly add the 'title: false' property? Please see possible lead to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660475/jqgrid-remove-tooltip-for-all-rows-columns

Comment: You can post your answer, It solved my problem, thank you!.
Also I suppose that you can control the content of this tooltip using the title attribute of the corresponding td.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

posting my answer, as you requested.

You can try having the property:

```
{title: false}
```

on the instantiation of your jqGrid to avoid this tooltip.

I hope this will help more people in the future.