# How to hide the tool-tip in struts2 jqgrid?

Tags: jquery, struts2, jqgrid, tooltip, struts2-jquery

I am using,

http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase/index.action

to showcase my grid. Here the tool-tip is visible on mouse over of all the rows. I want to hide the tool-tip.

Comment: See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7660674/315935)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is an example of [jqGrid](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html). You can remove titles by jquery in this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("table.ui-jqgrid-btable td").each(function(){
         $(this).removeAttr("title");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a helpful link that worked for me. Thanks to Palash Mondal.

http://burnignorance.com/javascript-performance-tips/hide-all-tool-tips-in-jqgrid/

Add this: cmTemplate: { title: false },