# Can you disable sortable columns globally with jqgrid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, jqgrid

I know you can go one by one and disable sorting of columns.  How can you disable it globally?  Or is it simply impossible?  Did I mention that this was an HTML table initially and converted to a jqgrid with the expansion function they have.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [column template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044047/stopping-columns-resizable-in-jqgrid/6047856#6047856). To set `sortable: false` for all columns of jqGrid or just to set it as the default value for the `sortable` property you can use

```
cmTemplate: {sortable: false}
```

as additional jqGrid option. If you use [tableToGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:table_to_jqgrid) then you should just add the same option to the second parameter of `tableToGrid`:

```
tableToGrid('#list', {cmTemplate: {sortable: false}});
```

**UPDATED**: I don't understand where you have any problem. [Here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/NonSortableTable.htm) you will find very simple demo which work. If you would click on any column header the grid will be not sorted.

Comment: cmTemplate...  That sounds like something worth trying.  So far, nothing has worked, including attempting to make each row unsortable

Comment: @DmainEvent. I posted demo example for you. See "UPDATED" part of my answer.