# Getting jqgrid row data typed according to colModel specs

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

jqgrid allows to specify type information as part of the colModel e.g.

```
editrules:{required:true, number: true},
```

Although this affects only the validation it would be nice to retrieve all row data
using this information.

```
jqGrid('getRowData')
```

returns all data as strings

Is it somehow possible to convert the result into typed information (a column with number: true should be converted to an integer in order to deal with it as an integer on the webserver side if JSON is used to encode/decode on submission of the grid data).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that jqGrid has **no** information about the type of data. There are formatter, sorting, editing and searching options to construct the editing or searching control, validation options and so on, but **no** information about the *type of data*.

Moreover jqGrid receive the input data in many cases as the strings. Even JavaScript type `number` is not what one really want to have because JavaScript don't have `integer` datatype for example.

The `getRowData` method uses unformatter to read the string content of the cells. In some cases, for example if you use `datatype: 'local'` and `data` parameter to fill the grid, the typed data are saved in internal `data` and `_index` parameters and you can uses the parameters to get *typed* information about the cell contain.

For example you if you define the column which hold the date the definition could be the following

```
{ name: 'invdate', index: 'invdate', width: 80, align: 'center',
    sorttype: 'date',
    formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'd-M-Y' }, editable: true,
    datefmt: 'd-M-Y',
    editoptions: {
        dataInit: function (elem) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(elem).datepicker({
                   dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
                    autoSize: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    changeMonth: true,
                    showButtonPanel: true,
                    showWeek: true
                });
            }, 100);
        }},
    editrules: {required: true, date: true},
    searchoptions: {
        sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'le', 'gt', 'ge'],
        dataInit: function (elem) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(elem).datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
                    autoSize: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    changeMonth: true,
                    showWeek: true,
                    showButtonPanel: true
                });
            }, 100);
        }}}
```

You see in how many places one have to specify the 'date' type.

I would recommend you to use column templates (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6047856/315935) for more information). In my projects which I implements for the customers I define (in one common JavaScript file) some templates like `dateTemplate` and defines the columns in the grid like

```
{name: 'invdate', index: 'invdate', width: 80, template: my.dateTemplate}
```

where `my.dateTemplate` is defined in the simplified form like

```
var my = {
    dateTemplate: {
        align: 'center',
        sorttype: 'date',
        formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'd-M-Y' }, editable: true,
        datefmt: 'd-M-Y',
        editoptions: {
            dataInit: function (elem) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(elem).datepicker({
                        dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
                        autoSize: true,
                        changeYear: true,
                        changeMonth: true,
                        showButtonPanel: true,
                        showWeek: true
                    });
                }, 100);
            }},
        editrules: {required: true, date: true},
        searchoptions: {
            sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'le', 'gt', 'ge'],
            dataInit: function (elem) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(elem).datepicker({
                        dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
                        autoSize: true,
                        changeYear: true,
                        changeMonth: true,
                        showWeek: true,
                        showButtonPanel: true
                    });
                }, 100);
            }}}
};
```

In the way the template play close role as the datatype. If you need you can write your own safe method based on `getRowData` and `template` parameter from the `colModel` to get the information which you need.