# Last row not showing after reloadGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I've got this code to create a grid table.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var mydata = [
{State:'Azerbaijan', cont:'Asia', '2009':'10100', '2008':'61600', '2007':'39200', '2006':'31900', '2005':'31800', '2004':'29500', '2003':'18600', '2002':'58', '2001':'57'},
{State:'Bosnia and Herzegovina', cont:'Europe', '2009':'96000', '2008':'123000', '2007':'121800', '2006':'136200', '2005':'131200', '2004':'121294', '2003':'112503', '2002':'102271', '2001':'95064'},
{State:'France', cont:'Europe', '2009':'345000', '2008':'389000', '2007':'427800', '2006':'442100', '2005':'437900', '2004':'446900', '2003':'444100', '2002':'463200', '2001':'713000', '2000':'701000', '1999':'694000'},
{State:'Germany', cont:'Europe', '2009':'291800', '2008':'605876', '2007':'551030', '2006':'515539', '2005':'647934', '2004':'667800', '2003':'660800', '2002':'652800', '2001':'651600', '2000':'643545', '1999':'633803'},
{State:'Greece', cont:'Europe', '2009':'134737', '2008':'162339', '2007':'167937', '2006':'164528', '2005':'165300', '2004':'166634', '2003':'167797', '2002':'165262', '2001':'163581', '2000':'167507', '1999':'170301'},
{State:'Iceland', cont:'Europe', '2009':'810000', '2008':'760000', '2007':'515000', '2006':'328424', '2005':'272400', '2004':'271300', '2003':'265900', '2002':'263528', '2001':'242526', '2000':'225721', '1999':'221433'},
{State:'Italy', cont:'Europe', '2009':'165800', '2008':'186400', '2007':'179500', '2006':'194200', '2005':'192900', '2004':'195400', '2003':'191400', '2002':'190400', '2001':'187400', '2000':'210000', '1999':'205567'},
{State:'Netherlands', cont:'Europe', '2009':'306000', '2008':'321200', '2007':'296900', '2006':'285300', '2005':'333800', '2004':'327000', '2003':'282800', '2002':'284400', '2001':'293200', '2000':'301700', '1999':'270000'},
{State:'Norway', cont:'Europe', '2009':'1125000', '2008':'1358800', '2007':'1362000', '2006':'1383000', '2005':'1391000', '2004':'1321700', '2003':'1192000', '2002':'1044000', '2001':'1100000', '2000':'1030000', '1999':'1000000'},
{State:'Poland', cont:'Europe', '2009':'10300', '2008':'29500', '2007':'57600', '2006':'55900', '2005':'53600', '2004':'58900', '2003':'57200', '2002':'58800', '2001':'45000', '2000':'45100', '1999':'46750'}
];
jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
  height: 500,
  width: 672,
  rowNum: -1,
  shrinkToFit:false,
    datatype: 'local',
    colNames:['State', 'cont','1999','2000','2001','2002','2003','2004','2005','2006','2007','2008','2009'],
    colModel :[ 
{name:'State', index:'State', width:170},
{name:'cont', index:'cont'},
{name:'1999', index:'1999', width:80, align:'right', formatter:'integer', sorttype:'integer', summaryType:'sum'},
{name:'2000', index:'2000', width:80, align:'right', formatter:'integer', sorttype:'integer', summaryType:'sum'},
{name:'2001', index:'2001', width:80, align:'right', formatter:'integer', sorttype:'integer', summaryType:'sum'},
{name:'2002', index:'2002', width:80, align:'right', formatter:'integer', sorttype:'integer', summaryType:'sum'},
{name:'2003', index:'2003', width:80, align:'right', formatter:'integer', sorttype:'integer', summaryType:'sum'},
{name:'2004', index:'2004', width:80, align:'right', formatter:'integer', sorttype:'integer', summaryType:'sum'},
{name:'2005', index:'2005', width:80, align:'right', formatter:'integer', sorttype:'integer', summaryType:'sum'},
{name:'2006', index:'2006', width:80, align:'right', formatter:'integer', sorttype:'integer', summaryType:'sum'},
{name:'2007', index:'2007', width:80, align:'right', formatter:'integer', sorttype:'integer', summaryType:'sum'},
{name:'2008', index:'2008', width:80, align:'right', formatter:'integer', sorttype:'integer', summaryType:'sum'},
{name:'2009', index:'2009', width:80, align:'right', formatter:'integer', sorttype:'integer', summaryType:'sum'} 
    ],
  sortname: 'State',
     grouping:true,
     groupingView : {
       groupField : ['cont'],
       groupSummary : [true],
       groupColumnShow : [true],
       groupText : ['<b>{0}</b>'],
       groupCollapse : false,
    groupOrder: ['asc']
     },
});
for(var i=0;i<=mydata.length;i++)
  jQuery("#list").jqGrid('addRowData',i+1,mydata[i]);
jQuery("#list").trigger("reloadGrid");
jQuery("#list").hideCol("cont");
</script>
```

And it works fine except the `jQuery("#list").trigger("reloadGrid");` won't draw the last row. But it's still there - it wont get counted towards the sum but when you sort by another column, another row becomes last and disapears and the former shows back.

Comment: better format that code to make it readable

Answer (score 5):

You main error is the usage of `rowNum: -1` instead of some large enough value like `rowNum: 10000`.

Moreover you should use `gridview: true` parameter of jqGrid and `data: mydata` instead of much more slow filling of grid with respect of `addRowData` (moreover you use `<=` in the loop instead of `<`).

Additionally I would recommend you to use [column templates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6047856/315935) which will reduce the code and can it more readable. The result of the changes you can see [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Quarath.htm).

Comment: Thank you. This was my first use of jQuary, so i actualy copy-pasted most from examples (ie http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) which had those mistakes.