# How to define grid as subgrid only once in subGridRowExpanded event instead defining it in every expand row operation

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

After discussing my requirement [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564434/how-to-show-total-of-subgrid-footer-data-in-parent-jqgrid-footer) & finalizing to implement it with grid as subgrid configuration, now I think instead of deining subgrid in every expand operation of main grid row [**in subGridRowExpanded event**] can I have jqGrid definition in such a way that subgrid should get defined only once. They should be made hidden & shown on subsequent collapse & expand operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand you correctly, but it seems that you need just set `reloadOnExpand: false` property of [subGridOptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asubgrid#properties).

Comment: Hi, yes your guessing was right. That's what I wanted to have in jqgrid.

Comment: Hi Oleg, I would like you to have a look into one of my issue posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326342/jquery-dialog-shows-data-from-previous-ajax-request). It is very prolong issue in my project. I would like to disucss it with you as you have helped me a lot in resolving jqGrid issue & this issue is surrounded by jqGrid use. I am not sure it is related to jqGrid; but I thought you can direct me in correct way to resolve it. Thanks