# jqGrid Searchbox "greater than" and "less than" are missing

Tags: jqgrid

How can i have greater than or lesser than in the Searchbox?

below is my search code:

```
{multipleSearch:true}
```

Searchbox is showing only this
[image: Searchbox]

Is there a settings that i need to set for jgGrid to recognize the field date as Date? it appears that it was being read as text.

below is my colModel for date

```
{name:'date', index:'date', width:90, editable:false, align:"center", editrules:{required:true}}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The behavior which you described exists since introduction of the new filter module in jqGrid. The default behavior is just a little too complex to be described in the "Default" column of the table from [the options of searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:singe_searching#options).

If you examine the source code of jqGrid you will find the following [two lines](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.1/js/grid.filter.js#L72-73):

```js
numopts : ['eq','ne', 'lt', 'le', 'gt', 'ge', 'nu', 'nn', 'in', 'ni'],
stropts : ['eq', 'ne', 'bw', 'bn', 'ew', 'en', 'cn', 'nc', 'nu', 'nn', 'in', 'ni'],
```

So if you have defined `sopt` property in the [searchoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:search_config#colmodel_options) for some column of jqGrid you will see the corresponding compare operations. You can set default

If you would define any `sorttype` value other as default `'string'` the numerical options will be used as the compare operations. Only for undefined `sorttype`, undefined `searchoptions.sopt` and undefined options of searching options `prmSearch` of [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator#definition) the behavior which you described will be used.

So you can use for example `navGrid` in the form

```js
$('#grid').jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager',
    {refreshstate: 'current', add: false, edit: false, del: false}, {}, {}, {},
    {sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'le', 'gt', 'ge', 'bw', 'bn', 'ew', 'en', 'cn', 'nc', 'nu', 'nn', 'in', 'ni']}
);
```

Another possibility is to define the `searchoptions.sopt` directly for the 'date' column:

```js
{name: 'date', index: 'date', width: 90, align: "center", editrules: {required: true},
    searchoptions: {sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'le', 'gt', 'ge']}}
```

You can include all operation which you want to have for the corresponding column depend on the type of the data inside.

What I really recommend you to do is to use [column templates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6047856/315935). In the projects which I developed for the customers I define in one JavaScript file which I include in all pages different templates for different types of data. For example

```js
var initDate = function (elem) {
        $(elem).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
            autoSize: true,
            changeYear: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            showWeek: true
        });
    },
    dateTemplate = {width: 80, align: 'center', sorttype: 'date',
        formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'm/d/Y' }, datefmt: 'm/d/Y',
        editoptions: {date: true, dataInit: initDate },
        searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'le', 'gt', 'ge'], dataInit: initDate }};
```

If you have defined the `dateTemplate` variable you can use it like

```js
{name:'date', index:'date', editrules: {required: true}, template: dateTemplate }
```

Comment: Thanks Oleg!! I opted to define the `searchoptions.sopt` directly for the **date** column. Its more simple and straight forward. I am slowly trying the column templates. Thanks again. :)