# Jqgrid Change values on inline edit

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have got a single grid on my page, and when it drops into inline edit mode there are some fields i would like to fill in (price based ones) as soon as the user has filled the first one in, for example they put a price of 50 in, i want to update the nett and gross fields.

Normally i would do this using a jquery blur function, but i'm not sure how to get the names of the input boxes on the grid, they seem to be a number depending on the row, then the name of the field.

Thanks
Luke

Answer (score 0):

Typically is you need update *the cell* after the user modified the cell value one use [cell editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:cell_editing) mode. In case of usage inline editing mode for *row* editing you have some options:

- you initialize inline editing with [keys: true](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#editrow) parameter and *the row* will be saved after the user press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. The user can any time discard the changes by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.
- you provide some button which the user can click to save the changes. You can use formatter: 'actions', [inlineNav](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#inlinenav) or your custom button to do this.
- You can implement saving of current editing *row* inside of `onSelectRow` or some other callback.

In any way the standard way in inline editing mode is working with rows without additional actions on cell basis. If you do need to bind `blur` or `focusout` event to all input fields of editing row you can use `dataEvents` with `type: 'blur'` (or `type: 'focusout'`). To easy define the [editoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editoptions) for all columns you can use `cmTemplate` option of jqGrid (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6047856/315935)).