# JQgrid: Picking the entire row vs clicked cell

Tags: jqgrid

Here are two different tables [@Oleg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/315935/oleg) made:

On the [first](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithISO8601Long.htm) one, when clicking a single cell - the entire row is picked.

On the [second](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/NonEditableCells.htm) one, only the clicked cell is picked.

This is being controlled with `cellEdit: true`.

I'd like to have a logic that will set `cellEdit` to false, but only for certain rows (under some condition, which for simplicity let's say this will happen when a cell's value is under 100).

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Your question isn't clear enough because you use reference the demo, which use **cell editing** mode, but you write about some rules for rows, which more corresponds **inline editing** mode. One can disable some **cells** from editing (in cell editing mode) by adding `"not-editable-cell"` class to the coresponding cells (using `cellattr`). One can disable editing of some **rows** (in inline editing mode) by adding `"not-editable-row"` class to the corresponding rows (using `rowattr`). What exactly you want to use cell editing or inline editing?

Comment: @Oleg, thanks. Well, I have a followup issue: I experienced with [this](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CustomFormAndInlineEdit.htm) example grid. When selecting some row and changing the value on the "Category" column, and then selecting a different row, the picked value isn't saved, and is restored to its initial value. Can you give me an example where the value is actually updated and not restored?

Comment: @Oleg, I'd like to do what you offered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9974305/3002584) on the third bulletpoint: "You can implement saving of current editing row inside of onSelectRow or some other callback."

Comment: Sorry, but I can't follow you. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CustomFormAndInlineEdit.htm), which you reference, is from [the old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4308172/315935), which is more as 6 years old. It uses `grid.jqGrid('editRow', id, **true**, null, null, 'clientArray');`, with `true` as the second parameter of `editRow`. It means that one need to press Enter to confirm saving. Clicking of another row without confirmation, calls `restoreRow` to discard the changes

Comment: Please answer on the following questions: 1) Which version of jqGrid you use (can use) and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). 2) Which one editing mode you want to use: cell editing or inline editing? 3) Could you modify the text of your question oriented on either cell editing or inline editing mode?

Comment: Right. I don't want to hit the Enter. I want to save the edited row when selecting another row. I just couldn't make that happen, so if there's an existing example, it would be nice.
Answering your questions: I can use free jqGrid, need to use inline editing.

Comment: Could you answer on my previous question? If you use inline editing for example then you can just replace `restoreRow` to `saveRow`, but I can't answer more till I don't know with which version and fork of jqGrid you work.

Comment: Inline editing can be used in at least 3 ways: 1) `formatter: "actions"`, which creates editing buttons in every row, 2) `inlineNav`, which creates editing buttons in navigator bar near to the pager buttons, 3) explicit calls of `editRow`, `saveRow` or `restoreRow` inside of some callbacks (`beforeSelectRow`, `onSelectRow`, `ondblClickRow`). The first two ways are standard ways, which are intuitive for every user. One still can implement any custom behavior using the 3-d way. You original question was about **selective** editing of some rows. You want prevent editing of some rows. Isn't so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow to edit data in some column one have to specify `editable` property in the column. [Free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) allows to use callback function as the value of `editable` property. The callback should return boolean value, which informs jqGrid, whether the cell is editable or not. [The wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/editable-property-of-colModel-as-function) describes the feature more detailed. For example, the following callback in some column `colModel` allows editing of the cells only if the value in `amount` column is less as 100:

```js
editable: function (options) {
    var item = $(this).jqGrid("getLocalRow", options.rowid);
    if (item.amount < 100) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Please refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42214322/jqgrid-make-the-select-drop-down-disappear) follow-up question.