# jqGrid plugin does not set the page number in URL

Tags: jqgrid

I have problem with jqGrid plugin. If I am on e.g. 2nd page, and I want to change the sorting direction of any column, to the server goes as a URL param `page=1` (but should be `page=2`) What's wrong ?

```html
<table id="list" class="scroll " cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>
<div id="pager" class="scroll" style="text-align:center;"></div>
```

```js
$(function () {

    $("#list").jqGrid({
        url: '/Control/UsersGridData/',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames: ['Name', 'User ID', 'Is Active', 'Last Action',  'Country'],
        colModel: [
  { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 120, align: 'center', sortable: true, search: true },
  { name: 'UserID', index: 'UserID', width: 120, align: 'center', sortable: true, search: true },
  { name: 'IsActive', index: 'IsActive', width: 50, align: 'center', sortable: true, search: true },
  { name: 'LastAction', index: 'LastAction', width: 90, align: 'center', sortable: true, search: true },
  { name: 'Country', index: 'Country', width: 40, align: 'center', sortable: true, search: true }],
        pager: jQuery('#pager'),
        rowNum: 20,
        rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
        sortname: 'Name',
        sortorder: "desc",
        viewrecords: true,
        imgpath: '/scripts/themes/coffee/images',
        width: '800'
    });
});
```

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use? I ask this because you use `class="scroll " cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"` and `class="scroll" style="text-align:center;"` attributes in HTML and you use `imgpath` which are not used in versions of jqGrid published in the last 3 years. For example [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:upgrade_from_3.4.x_to_3.5#options) you will read that `imgpath` is deprecated in jqGrid 3.5. The current version of jqGrid is 4.4.1.

Comment: from my jgGrid.src.js file - @license jqGrid  4.3.2  - jQuery Grid

Comment: I updated my answer with some small remarks to the code which could simplify it. The remarks are not concerned your main question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page number will be explicitly changed (see [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.base.js#L2013) of code [sortData](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.base.js#L2003) function used inside of [click](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.base.js#L2347-2360) event handler on the column header).

You can change the value inside of `onSortCol` event handler for example. You can get the value of current page directly from the corresponding `<input>` filed of pager: `$(pagerIdSelector).find("input.ui-pg-input").val()` where `var pagerIdSelector = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "pager")`.

In my opinion resetting the `pager` value to 1 is correct behavior. Let us you have some grid with 20 pages and the data are sorted by the first column in "asc" order. If the second page are displayed and the user clicks on the first column. In the case the sort order should be inverted to "desc". In the case the page number of the current page will be about 18 (it's 18 only if all pages are full with rows). If the user click on any other column and the grid should be sorted by *another column* then the rows displayed on the current page could have *any location* on the 20 pages sorted by the new criteria. Because of that jqGrid reset the value of `page` to 1 on every sorting of grid.

**UPDATED**: Some additional remarks to your code which are not important to your main question:

- jqGrid replaces `pager: jQuery('#pager')` to `pager: '#pager'` during initializing time. So it has no seance to make unneeded search of element by id. One should better always use id-selector syntax for `pager` option.
- `imgpath` option id [deprecated](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:upgrade_from_3.4.x_to_3.5#options) and it will be just ignored by jqGrid. So you should remove it.
- In the same way you call reduce HTML fragment needed for jqGrid to `<table id="list"></table><div id="pager"></div>`. All other attributes are deprecated and will be not used by jqGrid.
- The properties `sortable: true, search: true` are default (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options)) and one should remove it. In the same way if you use `index` with the same value as `name` you can remove definition of `index` property. If you want use `align: 'center'` in the most of your columns you can reduce and simplify your code if you would change the default value for the `align` property. After the usage of `cmTemplate: {align: 'center'}` option of jqGrid (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6047856/315935) for more information) you can remove `align: 'center'` in all columns. After all the changes the definition of all items of `colModel` will be short and clear like `{ name: 'Name', width: 120 }`.