# FilterToolBar not returning all matches

Tags: jqgrid

I have a *jqGrid* with json data type and `loadOnce: true`.  I am using the `filterToolBar` search.  It does not return all matches.  The grid contains a searchable column called *Name* and has values "Adkins, Joe" and "Adkinson, Jane".  If I type in search string "Adk", the only match returned is "Adkins, Joe".

Here is the grid definition:

```
function loadmyGrid(dataUrl, selectUrl) {
$("#myGrid").jqGrid({
    url: dataUrl + "?r=" + rand(),
    datatype: "json",
    mtype: 'GET',
    rowNum: -1,
    loadonce: true,
    ignoreCase: true,
    scroll: true,
    scrollOffset: 0,
    gridview: true,
    colNames: ["Employee ID", "Name", "User Name", ""],
    colModel: [
              { name: "EmployeeID", width: "125", align: "center", sortable: false, resizable: false, title: false, search: false },
                    { name: "Name", width: "150", align: "center", sortable: false, resizable: false, title: false },
                    { name: "UserName", width: "125", align: "center", sortable: false, resizable: false, title: false, search: false },
                    { name: "UserKey", key: true, width: "135", align: "center", sortable: false, resizable: false, title: false, formatter: selectButtonFormatter, search: false},
            ],
    emptyrecords: "Nothing to display",     
    beforeSelectRow: function () { return false; },
    gridComplete: function () {
        $("#myGrid").setGridHeight("100%");
        $("#myGrid").filterToolbar({searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: "cn" })
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main error is the usage of `rowNum: -1` which is wrong. If you want to prevent local paging of data you should use some large enough value of `rowNum`. For example `rowNum: 1000` or `rowNum: 10000`.

I recommend you additionally to replace `$("#myGrid")` inside of any callback (for example `gridComplete`) to `$(this)`. The usage of `"?r=" + rand()` part of the `url` seems me unneeded. The call of `$("#myGrid").filterToolbar` you should move outside of `gridComplete` because it can be called only once.

I recommend you additionally to use [column templates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6047856/315935). It can reduce the code and could make it more manageable and better readable.

Comment: Thanks Oleg! The rowNum setting fixed the search problem.  I will also implement your additional recommendations.