# jqGrid is not displaying java service response

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

jqGrid is not displaying the response returned by java service.

Html:

```
<table id="fbDetailTable" style="display: none"></table>
```

Java Script:

```
jQuery("#fbDetailTable").jqGrid({

url: "/ReportBatch/rs/ReportService/getFB?fB="+frtBill,
    datatype: "json",
colNames: ['Store Number', 'Order Number', 'SKU number',
           'Shipped Quantity','Order Created Date'],
colModel:[{name:'strNbr',index:'strNbr',width:100,jsonmap:'strNbr'},
          {name:'orderNbr',index:'orderNbr',width:100,jsonmap:'orderNbr'},
          {name:'skuNbr',index:'skuNbr',width:100,jsonmap:'skuNbr'},
          {name:'shpdQty',index:'shpdQty',width:100,jsonmap:'shpdQty'},
          {name:'ordCrtDt',index:'ordCrtDt',width:100,jsonmap:'ordCrtDt'}],
jsonReader: { repeatitems : false, strNbr: "0" },
viewrecords: true, 
loadonce:true,                                
    caption:"Order Details"
});
```

Service response:

```
[{"strNbr":"6310",
  "orderNbr":"10979577",
  "skuNbr":"646274",
  "shpdQty":"1",
  "ordCrtDt":"2013-01-29"},     
 {"strNbr":"6310",
  "orderNbr":"10979583",
  "skuNbr":"765992",
  "shpdQty":"3",
  "ordCrtDt":"2013-01-29"
 }]
```

Response Headers:

```
Content-Type    application/json
Date    Mon, 04 Feb 2013 20:21:24 GMT
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main error is that your input JSON data don't have "rows" property and place the data directly as array. In the case you should use

```js
root: function (obj) { return obj; }
```

inside of `jsonReader`. Moreover the setting `strNbr: "0"` is wrong. It should be `id: "strNbr"` instead.

It's very important additionally to use `rowNum` with some large enough value as the default value 25 (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options)). If you don't do this jqGrid will display only the 25 first row of data. It's not what you want.

Other important options which I strictly recommend you to use are: `gridview: true`, `autoencode: true`. The option `height: "auto"` is also very practical in the most scenarios. So the code should be about the following

```js
$("#fbDetailTable").jqGrid({
    url: "AVVD.json",
    datatype: "json",
    colNames: ["Store Number", "Order Number", "SKU number",
               "Shipped Quantity", "Order Created Date"],
    colModel: [
        { name: "strNbr" },
        { name: "orderNbr" },
        { name: "skuNbr" },
        { name: "shpdQty" },
        { name: "ordCrtDt" }
    ],
    cmTemplate: { width: 120 },
    jsonReader: {
        repeatitems: false,
        id: "strNbr",
        root: function (obj) {
            return obj;
        }
    },
    rowNum: 10000,
    gridview: true,
    autoencode: true,
    height: "auto",
    viewrecords: true,
    loadonce: true,
    caption: "Order Details"
});
```

You can additionally declare variables like

```js
var intTemplate = { sorttype: "integer", formatter: "integer" },
    dateTemplate = { sorttype: "date", formatter: "date" };
```

and use templates (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6047856/315935)) and modify `colModel` to the following

```js
colModel: [
    { name: "strNbr", template: intTemplate },
    { name: "orderNbr", template: intTemplate },
    { name: "skuNbr", template: intTemplate },
    { name: "shpdQty", template: intTemplate },
    { name: "ordCrtDt", template: dateTemplate }
]
```

The resulting demo you will see [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/AVVD.htm):

[image]