# jqGrid: reload data from json-string

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I know, that there is several similar questions are exists on SO, but despite it I creating this question because:
- I still don't get it :) 
- I want to create a topic that possibly will cover a problem more complete.

I reconstructed my production setup in simplified way, it available by link below. 
In short - I have simple jqGrid, that uses `jsonstring` as `dataType`, and `datastr` with JSON data. And then by firing this:

```
$("#grid").setGridParam({'datastr': myNewData}).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

Im trying to reload data in grid, but it just doesnt work.
What am I missing?

ps
Also it is matter for me, that grid has summary row which defined with `userdata`.

### [DOWNLOAD SETUP](http://www.sendspace.com/file/hgh7rv)

Answer (score 1):

It's very seldom that you really need to use `datatype` which values other as `"local"`, `"json"`, `"jsonp"` or `"xml"`. Most usage of other `datatype` can be easy replace to the tree main datatypes. If you use `"jsonstring"`, `"xmlstring"` or `"clientSide"` then the `datatype` will be **changed to `"local"`** after loading of data (see [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.4/js/grid.base.js#L1888) of source code for example). So if you really need to use `datatype: "jsonstring"` you can fix reloading by usage

```js
$("#grid").setGridParam({
    datastr: myNewData,
    datatype: "jsonstring" // !!! reset datatype
}).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

Additionally I could see that you used `pager: false` option of jqGrid. It's wrong option. If you don't need to use local paging of data I recommend you

1. don't include and `pager` option. Default value `pager: ""` is already OK.
2. include `rowNum` parameter with some large enough value like `rowNum: 10000`. Default value of `rowNum` is 20. So if you don't want to display only the first 20 rows of the input data you should increase the value of `rowNum`.

The last recommendation: you should include `sorttype: "integer"` (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options)) to columns which holds integer values. It will fix sorting of data if the user clicks on the column header. You should consider to use column templates too (see [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6047856/315935)).