# jqGrid reload datatype: local for each request

Tags: jqgrid

I am using jqGrid but due to my server side technology I cannot call a URL directly to get the data and can only post to the server via a 3rd party broker. My goal is to be able to load data into the Grid via calling my own JavaScript function that calls the server and returns a JSON string.

What I tried: instead of

```
url:'http://127.0.0.1/products/index.php’,
datatype: 'json',
```

I have

```
datastring:init(),
datatype: 'jsonstring',
```

my `init()` function does the server-side call. It works fine for the initial page load. However it is never called again e.g. when I jump between pages, or change the number of rows to view. I need it to recall my init function to refresh the data from the database. However it does not ever call my `init()` function more than once. I assume it thinks this is a hard coded string which never changes.

I tried to call `$("#mygrid").trigger("reloadGrid");` manually but it doesn’t seem to work either.

My Grid is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $("#list").jqGrid({
    datastr:init(),
    datatype: 'jsonstring',
    mtype: 'GET',
    beforeRequest: beforeReq,
    pager: '#pager',
    rowNum:5,
    rowList:[5,10,30],
    sortname: 'invid',
    sortorder: 'desc',
    grouping:true,
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,

  });
});
</script>
```

I tried calling

```
$("#list").setGridParam({datatype:'jsonstring', page:1}).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

I tried what Oleg has suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397671/jqgrid-reloadgrid-with-loadonce-set-to-true/5398136#5398136) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461597/jqgrid-reload-data-from-json-string)  but it still does not seem to call my init function again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You current code calls `init()` *once* **before** creating the grid. Then it create the grid using the result returned from `init()`.

If you really need to use `datatype: 'jsonstring'` (and not `datatype: "local"` with additional `data` parameter) then you can reset the value of `datastr` parameter before calling `reloadGrid`. The corresponding code could be about the following:

```js
$("#list").setGridParam({
    datatype: "jsonstring",
    datastr: init()
}).trigger("reloadGrid", [{page: 1}]);
```

Comment: thanks that seems to work. However I am not sure where to put this code. I tried putting it in beforeRequest function (http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events) but it ends up in a infinite loop

Comment: @Daveo: You don't posted where you used `$("#list").setGridParam({datatype:'jsonstring', page:1}).trigger('reloadGrid');` before. So it is difficult to answer where one should place it now place. If `init()` function run synchronously the you can just use `setGridParam` inside of  `beforeRequest` **without** usage of `reloadGrid`.

Comment: Excellent that seems to work  I can get data in the Grid. However paging does not change it always says 1 of 1 pages and there is no next page button even though I have 3 pages.
my page size = 10  . 

My JSON is

`
"total": "3", 
  "page": "1", 
  "records": "31",`


Next time I am in Germany I owe you a beer

Comment: @Daveo: You are welcome! You can try to use `datatype` defined as function (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#function)) if you really need to implement server side paging which is implemented without usage of jQuery.ajax internally.