# Filter is not working after making datatype local on grid complete

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, mvcjqgrid

currently i am facing one issue in jqgrid . After loading grid using ajax call, i am changing the datatype to local on grid complete. After that i m trying to filter but my getting zero records. Any help is appreciated.

**Below is my code:-**

```
$("#orderformtable").jqGrid(
            {
                url : "getOrderFormProductList.htm?VENDORID=" + VENDORID
                        + "&LOCATIONID=" + LOCATIONID,
                mtype : 'GET',
                datatype : "json",
                colNames : [ 'Product', 'Pipeline Qty.', 'A', 'B', 'C',
                        'D', 'Order Qty.' ],
                colModel : [ {
                    name : 'PRODUCT_NAME',
                    index : 'PRODUCT_NAME',
                    width : 80,
                    editable : false,
                    hidden : false,
                    editrules : {
                        required : true
                    },
                    editoptions : {
                        disabled : true,
                        size : "40",
                        maxlength : "70"
                    }

                }, {
                    name : 'PIPELINE_QTY',
                    index : 'PIPELINE_QTY',
                    width : 20,
                    editable : false,
                    editoptions : {
                        size : "7",
                        maxlength : "6"
                    },
                    editrules : {
                        required : true
                    },
                    align : 'center'
                }, {
                    name : 'MAX_QTY',
                    index : 'MAX_QTY',
                    width : 15,
                    editable : true,
                    editoptions : {
                        size : "7",
                        maxlength : "6"
                    },
                    editrules : {
                        required : true
                    },
                    align : 'center'
                }, {
                    name : 'INSTOCK_QTY',
                    index : 'INSTOCK_QTY',
                    width : 20,
                    editable : false,
                    editoptions : {
                        size : "7",
                        maxlength : "6"
                    },
                    editrules : {
                        required : true
                    },
                    align : 'center'
                }, {
                    name : 'VENDOR_PIPELINE',
                    index : 'VENDOR_PIPELINE',
                    width : 20,
                    editable : false,
                    editoptions : {
                        size : "7",
                        maxlength : "6"
                    },
                    editrules : {
                        required : true
                    },
                    align : 'center'
                }, {
                    name : 'REQUIRED_QTY',
                    index : 'REQUIRED_QTY',
                    width : 20,
                    editable : false,
                    editoptions : {
                        size : "7",
                        maxlength : "6"
                    },
                    editrules : {
                        required : true
                    },
                    align : 'center'
                }, {
                    name : 'REORDER_QTY',
                    index : 'REORDER_QTY',
                    width : 20,
                    editable : true,
                    search : false,
                    editoptions : {
                        size : "7",
                        maxlength : "6"
                    },
                    editrules : {
                        required : true
                    },
                    align : 'center'
                } ],
                loadonce : true,
                localReader : {
                    repeatitems : true
                },
                hidegrid : false,
                postData : {},
                rowNum : 200,
                rowList : [ 200, 220, 230 ],
                height : 500,
                autowidth : true,
                rownumbers : true,
                pager : '#orderformpagination',
                sortname : 'PRODUCT_NAME',
                viewrecords : true,
                gridview : true,
                sortorder : "asc",
                caption : "",
                emptyrecords : "Empty records",
                loadonce : false,
                gridComplete : function() {
                    $("#orderformtable").setGridParam( {
                        datatype : 'local',
                        ignoreCase : true
                    });
                },
                loadComplete : function() {

                    var rowid = jQuery("#orderformtable").jqGrid(
                            'getDataIDs');
                    for ( var i = 0; i < rowid.length; i++) {

                        $('#orderformtable').jqGrid('editRow', rowid[i]);
                    }
                }
            });
```

**below is my jsonarray retruned form controller:-**

```
{
"total": 1,
"rows": [
    {
        "cell": [
            "Ball Pen",
            4,
            100,
            10,
            0,
            90
        ],
        "id": "1220"
    },
    {
        "cell": [
            "BATTERY DURACELL 9V PER PC",
            1,
            50,
            10,
            0,
            40
        ],
        "id": "1101"
    },
    {
        "cell": [
            "Brown Tape 2 inch per pc",
            0,
            30,
            10,
            0,
            20
        ],
        "id": "1108"
    },
    {
        "cell": [
            "CELLO TAPE 1 INCH- PER PC",
            0,
            80,
            10,
            0,
            70
        ],
        "id": "1115"
    },
    {
        "cell": [
            "CUTTER PAPER MEDIUM",
            0,
            25,
            10,
            0,
            15
        ],
        "id": "1122"
    },
    {
        "cell": [
            "Scissor big (per pc)",
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
        ],
        "id": "1199"
    }
],
"records": 6,
"page": 1
```

}

Comment: As you have set   `loadonce : true,` you may not need to set `datatype : 'local'`

Comment: And you have set `loadonce` twice( first time true, then false). Remove the second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the main problem which you have is the usage of both `loadonce: true` and `loadonce: false`. Definition of an object with the same property defined twice will be interpreted as error mostly, but if the web browser do interpret the value of the property as `loadonce: false` then you can have the problem which you describe.

The setting of `datatype` to `'local'` inside of `gridComplete` is very bad. Probably you get the trick from some very old code example. If you use `loadonce: true` then

1. the data from the server will be saved locally and so one can search/filter the data locally.
2. the `datatype` will be *automatically* changed to `"local"` *after* first loading the data from the server and *after* saving the data locally.

If you set `datatype` to `'local'` inside of `gridComplete` then **the data loaded from the server will be not saved locally**. So you can't use local filtering of the data.

Additionally I would recommend you to reduce you code by usage of column templates. You can use `cmTemplate` for example to change the default values of any property from the item of `colModel` (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6047856/315935)). You can remove additionally many options (`postData: {}`, `localReader: { repeatitems: true }`, `sortorder : "asc"`, `mtype : 'GET'`, `caption : ""`) which have default values. As the result your code could be rewritten to something like the following

```js
$("#orderformtable").jqGrid({
    url: "getOrderFormProductList.htm",
    postData: {
        VENDORID: function () { return VENDORID; },
        LOCATIONID: function () { return LOCATIONID; }
    },
    datatype: "json",
    colNames: [ 'Product', 'Pipeline Qty.', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'Order Qty.' ],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'PRODUCT_NAME', width: 80, align: 'left' },
        { name: 'PIPELINE_QTY' },
        { name: 'MAX_QTY', width: 15, template: 'myIntTemplate' },
        { name: 'INSTOCK_QTY' },
        { name: 'VENDOR_PIPELINE'},
        { name: 'REQUIRED_QTY' },
        { name: 'REORDER_QTY', editable: true, search: false }
    ],
    cmTemplate: { width: 20, align: 'center', editrules: { required: true },
        editoptions: { size: "7", maxlength: "6" }
    },
    loadonce: false,
    hidegrid: false,
    rowNum: 200,
    rowList: [ 200, 220, 230 ],
    height: "auto",
    autowidth: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    pager: '#orderformpagination',
    sortname: 'PRODUCT_NAME',
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    emptyrecords: "Empty records",
    ignoreCase: true,
    loadComplete: function() {
        var i, $self = $(this), rowids = $self.jqGrid('getDataIDs');
        for (i = 0; i < rowids.length; i++) {
            $self.jqGrid('editRow', rowids[i]);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Oleg... appreciated your quick response.. :):)