# Jqgrid SCRIPT5007: unable to get value of the property 'NUM_PEDIDO' object is null or undefined

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

The error occurs when returning the JSON data for jqGrid.

See Config a colModel my Jqgrid:

```
        colModel:[
                    {name:'NUM_PEDIDO', index:'NUM_PEDIDO', width:80, align:"center", key: true},
                    {name:'NOM_SITUACAO', index:'NOM_SITUACAO', width:70, align:"center"},
                    {name:'QTD_ANEXO', index:'QTD_ANEXO', width:55, align:"center"},
                    {name:'COD_PRESTADOR', index:'COD_PRESTADOR', width:90, align:"center"},
                    {name:'DATA_AUTORIZACAO', index:'DATA_AUTORIZACAO', width:90, align:"center"},
                    {name:'ITEM_MEDICO', index:'ITEM_MEDICO', width:110, align:"center"},
                    {name:'COD_DENTE_REGIAO', index:'COD_DENTE_REGIAO', width:110, align:"center"},
                    {name:'IND_FACE_LP', index:'IND_FACE_LP', width:30, align:"center"},
                    {name:'IND_FACE_V', index:'IND_FACE_V', width:15, align:"center"},
                    {name:'IND_FACE_M', index:'IND_FACE_M', width:15, align:"center"},
                    {name:'IND_FACE_D',index:'IND_FACE_D', width:15, align:"center"},
                    {name:'IND_FACE_OI', index:'IND_FACE_OI', width:30, align:"center"},
                    {name:'IND_SITUACAO', index:'IND_SITUACAO', width:60, align:"center"},
                    {name:'COD_GLOSA_PRIORIDADE_AUT', index:'COD_GLOSA_PRIORIDADE_AUT', width:50, align:"center"},
                    {name:'NUM_GUIA', index:'NUM_GUIA', width:75, align:"center"},
                    {name:'TIPO_SITUACAO', index:'TIPO_SITUACAO', width:100, align:"center"},
                    {name:'DAT_REALIZACAO', index:'DAT_REALIZACAO', width:100, align:"center"},                                        
                    {name:'NOME_SITUACAO_PGTO', index:'NOME_SITUACAO_PGTO', width:100, align:"center"},
                    {name:'COD_GLOSA_PRIORIDADE_PGTO', index:'COD_GLOSA_PRIORIDADE_PGTO', width:100, align:"center"},
                    {name:'DT_PAGAMENTO', index:'DT_PAGAMENTO', width:100, align:"center"},
                    {name:'IND_SITUACAO_REV', index:'IND_SITUACAO_REV', width:135, align:"center"},
                    {name:'COD_GLOSA_PRIORIDADE_REVISAO', index:'COD_GLOSA_PRIORIDADE_REVISAO', width:120, align:"center"}
```

See JSON:

```
{"Items":[{"page":1,"total":1,"records": 4 ,"items":[ { "NUM_PEDIDO":"8476",  "NOM_SITUACAO":"Autorizado",  "QTD_ANEXO":"0",  "COD_PRESTADOR":"11067322",  "DATA_AUTORIZACAO":"28/10/2013",  "ITEM_MEDICO":"85100226",  "COD_DENTE_REGIAO":"35",  "IND_FACE_LP":"S",  "IND_FACE_V":"S",  "IND_FACE_M":"S",  "IND_FACE_D":"S",  "IND_FACE_OI":"",  "IND_SITUACAO":"A",  "COD_GLOSA_PRIORIDADE_AUT":"0",  "NUM_GUIA":"",  "TIPO_SITUACAO":"",  "DAT_REALIZACAO":"",  "NOME_SITUACAO_PGTO":"",  "COD_GLOSA_PRIORIDADE_PGTO":"0",  "DT_PAGAMENTO":"",  "IND_SITUACAO_REV":"",  "COD_GLOSA_PRIORIDADE_REVISAO":"0"},{ "NUM_PEDIDO":"8476",  "NOM_SITUACAO":"Autorizado",  "QTD_ANEXO":"0",  "COD_PRESTADOR":"11067322",  "DATA_AUTORIZACAO":"28/10/2013",  "ITEM_MEDICO":"85100226",  "COD_DENTE_REGIAO":"35",  "IND_FACE_LP":"S",  "IND_FACE_V":"S",  "IND_FACE_M":"S",  "IND_FACE_D":"S",  "IND_FACE_OI":"",  "IND_SITUACAO":"A",  "COD_GLOSA_PRIORIDADE_AUT":"0",  "NUM_GUIA":"",  "TIPO_SITUACAO":"",  "DAT_REALIZACAO":"",  "NOME_SITUACAO_PGTO":"",  "COD_GLOSA_PRIORIDADE_PGTO":"0",  "DT_PAGAMENTO":"",  "IND_SITUACAO_REV":"",  "COD_GLOSA_PRIORIDADE_REVISAO":"0"},{ "NUM_PEDIDO":"8476",  "NOM_SITUACAO":"Autorizado",  "QTD_ANEXO":"0",  "COD_PRESTADOR":"11067322",  "DATA_AUTORIZACAO":"28/10/2013",  "ITEM_MEDICO":"85100226",  "COD_DENTE_REGIAO":"35",  "IND_FACE_LP":"S",  "IND_FACE_V":"S",  "IND_FACE_M":"S",  "IND_FACE_D":"S",  "IND_FACE_OI":"",  "IND_SITUACAO":"A",  "COD_GLOSA_PRIORIDADE_AUT":"0",  "NUM_GUIA":"",  "TIPO_SITUACAO":"",  "DAT_REALIZACAO":"",  "NOME_SITUACAO_PGTO":"",  "COD_GLOSA_PRIORIDADE_PGTO":"0",  "DT_PAGAMENTO":"",  "IND_SITUACAO_REV":"",  "COD_GLOSA_PRIORIDADE_REVISAO":"0"},{ "NUM_PEDIDO":"8476",  "NOM_SITUACAO":"Autorizado",  "QTD_ANEXO":"0",  "COD_PRESTADOR":"11067322",  "DATA_AUTORIZACAO":"28/10/2013",  "ITEM_MEDICO":"85100226",  "COD_DENTE_REGIAO":"35",  "IND_FACE_LP":"S",  "IND_FACE_V":"S",  "IND_FACE_M":"S",  "IND_FACE_D":"S",  "IND_FACE_OI":"",  "IND_SITUACAO":"A",  "COD_GLOSA_PRIORIDADE_AUT":"0",  "NUM_GUIA":"",  "TIPO_SITUACAO":"",  "DAT_REALIZACAO":"",  "NOME_SITUACAO_PGTO":"",  "COD_GLOSA_PRIORIDADE_PGTO":"0",  "DT_PAGAMENTO":"",  "IND_SITUACAO_REV":"",  "COD_GLOSA_PRIORIDADE_REVISAO":"0"}, ]}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't posted more full code which you use. The format of the input JSON data which you use is other as default expected by jqGrid (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#json_data)). So you have to specify `jsonReader` option like below to inform jqGrid here it can get the required information:

```
jsonReader: {
    root: "Items.0.items",
    page: "Items.0.page",
    total: "Items.0.total",
    records: "Items.0.records",
    repeatitems: false
}
```

I would recommend you additionally to remove all `index` properties from `colModel` and remove common `align:"center"` property. Default value of `align` is `"left"`. If you have `colModel` with more columns with another orientation you should change the defaults by jqGrid option

```
cmTemplate: { align: "center" }
```

In the case you can remove `align:"center"` property from all `colModel` items. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6047856/315935) for more information.

**UPDATED**: [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/cavalsilva.htm) demonstrate that the above `jsonReader` can read the data which you posted. Additional modification which I made in your data: 1) I removed `,` after the last item. 2) I modified value of `NUM_PEDIDO` property in JSON data to make the data unique (you use `key: true` from `NUM_PEDIDO` column which mean that the column contains *unique* values).

Comment: See my jsonReader
            jsonReader: {
                repeatitems: false,
                root: function (obj) { return obj.Items[0].items; },
                page: function (obj) { return obj.Items[0].page; },
                total: function (obj) { return obj.Items[0].total; },
                records: function (obj) { return obj.Items[0].records; }
            }

Comment: @cavalsilva: you should include **more full JavaScript code which you use**. The options `datatype`, `loadonce`, `jsonReader` are very important. It's important to know how you fill the grid. Do you use `datatype: "json"` and the JSON data which you posted are from the server response or you use `datatype: "local"` or `dadatype: "jsonstring"`? You should don't post any important information in comments. Instead of that you should click on "edit" link below your question, modify/append the text of your question and post comment to inform other about your modifications.

Comment: I remove all index and align and the error continued, I use datatype:"json".

Comment: @cavalsilva: correct `jsonReader` should solve your problem. Other suggestion only for reducing your code and making it more readable. If your problem not solved then you don't posted important part of your JavaScript code in your question.

Comment: @cavalsilva: Do you reduced your original JSON response to 4 items manually? The JSON data which you posted are wrong because of `,` after the 4-th (the last) item (see `}, ]}]}`).

Comment: **My default jsonReader with jqgrid null**

{"Items":[{"page":1,"total":0,"records":0,"items":[]}]}

**My jsonReader is there:**
            `jsonReader: {
                repeatitems: false,
                root: function (obj) { return obj.Items[0].items; },
                page: function (obj) { return obj.Items[0].page; },
                total: function (obj) { return obj.Items[0].total; },
                records: function (obj) { return obj.Items[0].records; }
            }`

And I see my JSON at feedly and stay correct.

Comment: @cavalsilva: I updated my answer. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/cavalsilva.htm) works.

Comment: Thanks @Oleg, this problem is the `,` at last item the json.