# how to pass my id to controller from jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, delete-row

I am working in the concrete5 cms, I trying to implement jqgrid in my web application. I did jqgrid view in the form but i dont know howw to edit, delete and all function in the jqgrid.

the problem was if I select the row in the jqgrid and delete, it was deleted in the front view but how to delete in my database and how to pass the sID value to my controller.

[image]

```
var myData = <?php echo json_encode($sl) ?>;

    $("#statGrid").jqGrid({
        caption: 'Status List',
        datatype:'local',
        data: myData,
        mtype:'POST',
        colNames:['sID','Status Name','Type','Description'],
        colModel:[ 
            {name:'status_id',editable:true }, 
            {name:'status_name',editable:true },
            {name:'status_type',editable:true },
            {name:'status_description', editable:true, edittype: 'textarea' } ],
        width: "777",
        height: "auto",
        pager:'#statPager',
        rowNum:5, 
        rowList:[5,10,20,30],
        rownumbers: true,
        viewrecords: true,
        recreateForm:true,
        gridView: true,
        autoencode: true,
        editurl: "editStatus",
        loadui:'enable'

    }).navGrid("#statPager",{add:false, edit:true, view:false, del:true, search:false, refresh:false });
```

How to pass exact sID through parameter in the grid. please guide me about the jqgrid. to solve this problem. if any mistake in my question sorry, i will develop my question skillthanks.

Comment: can you post your code once

Comment: my code was added please check @udaykiranpulipati

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that `'status_id'` column contains unique ids which you want to see on the server side in the URL `"editStatus"`. In the case you should add `key: true` to the definition of `'status_id'` column. In the case the value from the column will be used as the rowid (the value of `id` attribute of `<tr>` elements of the grid which represent the rows of data). The data, which will be posted to the server during deleting of the row, are described [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#what_is_posted_to_the_server2).

Small remarks to your code. You should replace `gridView: true` to `gridview: true`, change `width: "777"` to `width: 777`, remove `recreateForm:true` (bacause it's the option of form editing and not the option of jqGrid). If you need set some common values to `colModel` like `editable:true` you can remove the properties `editable:true` from `colModel` and uses jqGrid option `cmTemplate: {editable: true}` instead. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6047856/315935) for details.

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply and your suggestions @Oleg . still i have problem in the 'editurl'.... In the firebug show the data of id and oper but in my controller not get the value, so what i did wrong

Comment: I change gridview, width and remove recreateForm and also added the cmTemplate its working fine thanks once again

Comment: You are welcome! If you see that *correct information* will be sent to the server then you should verify your server code. It should just read the `id` and `oper`.

Comment: Hi sorry i have one more question, this following code is not working may i know why? 'navGrid("#statPager",{add:false, edit:true, view:false, del:true, search:false, refresh:false },
    {reloadAfterSubmit: true, jqModal: true, closeOnEscape: true, closeAfterEdit: true},
    {closeOnEscape: true});' the closeonEscape in the delete not working?

Comment: @KumarShanmugam: Thanks! Is the problem is solved now?