# Unable to get property 'stype' of undefined or null reference

Tags: jqgrid

I using jqgrid filtertoolbar. I'm having some 4 select filter in that. When i tried to select one of the values in any `select` box i'm getting the following error.

```
Unable to get property 'stype' of undefined or null reference
```

Is there any general error or missing value that i have done anywhere in my code.

//Code:

Sample of colModel:

colModel:

```
 jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'ManageCandidateDetails.aspx/GetAllCandidateDetails',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            // debugger;
            genericResult = $.parseJSON(data.d);
            //  debugger;
            jQuery("#CandidateDetailsGrid").jqGrid({
                data: genericResult.candidateDetails,
                datatype: "local",
                // colNames: ['CandidateId', 'Email', 'Name'],
                //colModel: [{ name: 'CandidateId', index: 'CandidateId', width: 75}, { name: 'Email', index: 'Email', width: 75 }, { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 100}],
                colNames: ['CandidateId', 'Name', 'Email', 'DOB', 'Gender', 'Qualification', 'Department', 'OtherQual', 'OtherDept', 'Exp(Years)', 'Exp(Months)', 'Mobile', 'Country', 'State', 'City', 'ZipCode', 'FilePath', 'Sel.Status', 'CreatedDate', 'ModifiedDate', 'ModifiedBy', 'Status', 'LastLoginTime'],
                colModel: [{ name: 'CandidateId', index: 'CandidateId', width: 75, editable: true },
                           { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 100, editable: true },
                           { name: 'Email', index: 'Email', width: 75, editable: true },
                           { name: 'DOB', index: 'DOB', width: 50, editable: true, searchoptions: { dataInit: newDatePick }, editoptions: { dataInit: newDatePick} },
                           { name: 'Gender', index: 'Gender', width: 50, editable: true },
                           { name: 'Qualification', index: 'Qualification', width: 75, editable: true, stype: 'select', editoptions: { value: ":All;" + genericResult.qualification} },
                           { name: 'Department', index: 'Department', width: 75, editable: true, stype: 'select', editoptions: { value: ":All;" + genericResult.department} },
                           { name: 'OtherQual', index: 'OtherQual', width: 75, editable: true },
                           { name: 'OtherDept', index: 'OtherDept', width: 75, editable: true },
                           { name: 'ExperienceYears', index: 'ExperienceYears', width: 75, editable: true },
                           { name: 'ExperienceMonths', index: 'ExperienceMonths', width: 75, editable: true },
                           { name: 'Mobile', index: 'Mobile', width: 100, editable: true },
                           { name: 'Country', index: 'Country', width: 100, editable: true, stype: 'select', formatter: 'select', edittype: 'select',
                               searchoptions: {
                                   value: allCountries, stype: 'select'

                               },
                               editoptions: {
                                   value: allCountries,
                                   dataInit: removeTheOptionAll,
                                   dataEvents: [
                            { type: "change", fn: function (e) { changeStateSelect($(e.target).val(), e.target); } }
                        ]
                               }
                           },
                           { name: 'state', index: 'state', width: 100, formatter: "select", stype: "select",
                               editable: true, edittype: "select",
                               editoptions: { value: allStates, dataInit: removeTheOptionAll },
                               searchoptions: { value: allStates }
                           },
                           { name: 'City', index: 'City', width: 50, editable: true },
                           { name: 'ZipCode', index: 'ZipCode', width: 50, editable: true },
                           { name: 'FilePath', formatter: function () { return "<img src='../Images/error.png' alt='my image' />"; }, unformat: imageUnFormat, index: 'FilePath', width: 50 },
                           { name: 'SelectedStatus', index: 'SelectedStatus', width: 75, edittype: 'checkbox', formatter: 'checkbox', editable: true, editoptions: { value: "1:Yes;0:No" }, stype: 'select', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq'], value: "All:All;1:Yes;0:No"} },
                           { name: 'CreatedDate', index: 'CreatedDate', width: 75, formatoptions: { srcformat: "ISO8601Long", newformat: "d/m/Y h:i A" },
                               searchoptions: { dataInit: datePick }, editoptions: { dataInit: datePick }
                           },
                           { name: 'ModifiedDate', index: 'ModifiedDate', width: 75, formatoptions: { srcformat: "ISO8601Long", newformat: "d/m/Y h:i A" },
                               searchoptions: { dataInit: datePick }, editoptions: { dataInit: datePick }
                           },
                           { name: 'Modifiedby', index: 'ModifiedBy', width: 75 },
                           { name: 'Status', index: 'Status', width: 50, edittype: 'checkbox', editable: true, stype: 'select', searchoptions: { value: "All:All;1:Yes;2:No"} },
                           { name: 'LastLoginTime', index: 'LastLoginTime', width: 75, formatoptions: { srcformat: "ISO8601Long", newformat: "d/m/Y h:i A" },
                               searchoptions: { dataInit: datePick, attr: { title: 'Select Date'} }, editoptions: { dataInit: datePick }
                           }],
                rowNum: 10,
                mtype: 'GET',
                loadonce: true,
                rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                pager: '#CandidateDetailsGridPager',
                sortname: 'CandidateId',
                viewrecords: true,
                caption: "Candidate Details",
                ignoreCase: true,
                gridview: true,
                rownumbers: true

            });

            jQuery("#CandidateDetailsGrid").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: "cn" });

            $('#CandidateDetailsGrid').jqGrid('navGrid', '#CandidateDetailsGridPager',
               {
                   edit: true,
                   add: true,
                   del: true,
                   search: true,
                   searchtext: "Search",
                   addtext: "Add",
                   edittext: "Edit",
                   deltext: "Delete"
               },
               { // edit option
                   beforeShowForm: function (form) {

                   }
               },
               { // add option

                   addcaption: 'Add Candidate Detail',
                   beforeShowForm: function (form) {
                       //debugger;
                       $("#myFormError").remove();
                       $('#tr_LastLoginTime', form).hide();
                       $('#tr_CandidateId', form).hide();
                       $('#tr_Modifiedby', form).hide();
                       $('#tr_ModifiedDate', form).hide();
                       $('#tr_CreatedDate', form).hide();
                   },
                   onclickSubmit: function (response, postData) {
                       debugger;
                       $("#FormError").text("");
                       $("<tr id='myFormError'><td colspan='2'><div style='background-color:green;color:white; font-weight:bold; width:100%;padding-left:5px;'>Success</div></td></tr>").insertAfter("#FormError");


                   }
               }
               );

        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });

    //Unformat the image during the edit.
    function imageUnFormat(cellvalue, options, cell) {
        return cellvalue
    }
```

Comment: Which `datatype` you use? Do you use `loadonce: true`? If you use `datatype: "local"` or remote `datatype` (`"json"` or `"xml"`), but with `loadonce: true` then you **have to** use `index` the same as `name`. On the other side you use `name: 'Sel.Status', index: 'SelectedStatus'` which is wrong. You should include more full code. Do you have the demo which reproduce the error? In which line of `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` of jqGrid 4.6 you have the error?

Comment: @Oleg: The issue is with the name and index as u said. The error is been fixed now. But the filter isn't working. I'll post the full code now.

Comment: `loadonce: true` will be ignored if you use `datatype: "local"`. The line `genericResult = $.parseJSON(data.d)` shows indirectly on an error on your server side. You makes probably **unneeded additional conversion of JSON** of the object with data. ASP.NET makes the conversion for you already. You need just return `object` and not `string`. Another thing: I recommend you to *remove* all `index` property from `colModel`. I recommend additionally to use column `template` (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6047856/315935)). It can dramatically reduce the code and makes it more readable.

Comment: You wrote "the filter isn't working". It gives almost no information. What exactly not work? By the way you can remove `colNames` if it contains only the same values like `name` properties of `colModel`.

Comment: @Oleg: When i type the column value in the filter for which the value is in the grid it doesn't show me the filtered result. Just it shows blank grid(no results).

Comment: You should provide **the demo** (for example in jsfiddle) with **test data** (2 rows for example). The demo should use `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`. You should provide the test case to reproduce the problem: what one should type exactly in which column and so on.