# extend jqgrid for colModel edittype

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, datepicker

I am going to use JqGrid for many different web pages.
And I have some custom formatter, and custom edittype
for example, I want to use datepicker to edit dates

so, instead of using colModel's edittype as custom, and provide custom functions to do that, I would like "if possible" to write an extension to jqgrid edittype, so I can just write "date", and I will write an extension to replace it with the datepickeer.
As I said, it is for re-usability, so instead of doing custom edit type for every web page/jqgrid, I could do it only once in that place.
Is there any documentation on how to extend jqgrid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with custom formatter. jqGrid support [predefined formatters](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter) like `formatter: "integer"`, `formatter: "date"`. You can *"register"* your [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter) and [unformatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter#unformatting) as one more value which you can use. For example if you want to register `formatter: "myCheckbox"` you need define `$.fn.fmatter.myCheckbox` as formetter function and `$.fn.fmatter.myCheckbox.unformat` as unformatter function.

```
$.extend($.fn.fmatter, {
    myCheckbox: function (cellValue, options, rowObject) { 
        // the code of the custom formatter is here
        ...
    }
});
$.extend($.fn.fmatter.myCheckbox, {
    unformat: function (cellValue, options, elem) {
        // the code of the custom unformatter is here
        ...
    }
});
```

The code from [here](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid-plugins/blob/master/jQuery.jqGrid.checkboxFontAwesome4.js) uses Font Awesome 4.x and register new `formatter: "checkboxFontAwesome4"`. "Registering" of custom formatters can simplify your code.

The next feature. jqGrid supports *column templates* starting with version 3.8.2 jqGrid (see [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6047856/315935)). It allows you to define *common settings* used in `colModel` as one object and to use `template` property in `colModel`. For example if you have many columns which contains numbers you can define for example `numberTemplate` object as

```
var numberTemplate = {
        formatter: "number", align: "right", sorttype: "number", width: 60,
        searchoptions: {
            sopt: ["eq", "ne", "lt", "le", "gt", "ge"]
        }
    };
```

then you can define tree columns `"tax"`, `"amount"` and `"total"` as

```
colModel: [
    ...
    { name: "tax", template: numberTemplate },
    { name: "amount", template: numberTemplate },
    { name: "total", width: 70, template: numberTemplate },
    ...
]
```

In the way you defines columns where all the properties from `numberTemplate` will be applied in the columns. The default `width: 60` defined in `numberTemplate` will be overwritten to the value `width: 70` for the column "total".

The usage of column templates allows you to define *once* in your code templates for dates which uses jQuery UI Datepicker for example and uses in every column of every grid of your project just the corresponding reference on the template.

The current version of jqGrid on github supports "registering" of templates as strings. So the next version (higher as 4.6.0), which I hope will be soon released, will support the following syntax:

```
$.extend($.jgrid, {
    cmTemplate: {
        myNumber: {
            formatter: "number", align: "right", sorttype: "number",
            searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne", "lt", "le", "gt", "ge"] }
        }
    }
});
```

(in the example I didn't included `width` in the template)

```
colModel: [
    ...
    { name: "tax", width: 52, template: "number" },
    { name: "amount", width: 75, template: "number" },
    { name: "total", width: 60, template: "number" },
    ....
]
```

See [the pull request](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/pull/631) for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot Oleg
you are very helpful. I am interested in this one on the github.
Does it work with jquery 1.7?
and do i need to do any build for it? Can I just download it and use the one with minimized file?

Comment: @gkar: I'm not sure whether the current code works with old version jQuery (1.7.2). If you open `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` you will see the comment with `Modules: grid.base.js; jquery.fmatter.js; grid.custom.js; grid.common.js; grid.formedit.js; grid.filter.js; grid.inlinedit.js; grid.celledit.js; jqModal.js; jqDnR.js; grid.subgrid.js; grid.grouping.js; grid.treegrid.js; grid.pivot.js; grid.import.js; JsonXml.js; grid.tbltogrid.js; grid.jqueryui.js; 
*/`. So you can concatenate the files in the order to get `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` and use any minimizer to get minimized file.

Comment: Appreciate your help a lot

Answer (score 0):

As with any jQuery plugin, you can extend the plugin with $.extend() like this:

```
(function($) {
    var extensionMethods = {
        // ...
    };

    $.extend(true,$.jgrid, extensionMethods);

})(jQuery);
```