# Hide a column while viewing selected row from JQGrid pager button.

Tags: jqgrid, mvcjqgrid, jqgrid-inlinenav

I have one column in JQGrid.

```
{ name: 'Action', index: 'Action', width: 70, sortable: false, formatter: 'actions', formatoptions: { keys: true, editformbutton: false, editbutton: true, delbutton: false } }
```

I want to hide the above column while viewing a selected row from JQGrid pager button. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: You should describe more clear what you need. You wrote about "viewing", but you used editing featues. You set `editformbutton: false`, so one will start *inline editing* inside of the grid. You wrote about "hiding" of "the above column". Which column you mean (the `'Action'` column)? Where hiding? If you mean [View](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#viewgridrow) feature then you probably mean hiding the column information in the View dialog? In any way you should describe more clear what you need to implement.

Comment: @Oleg, I have a JQGrid having some columns along with **Action** column. I use this column for inline editing the grid. But I don't want to show this column to user when they view a selected row using NavGrid pager **view** button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add `viewable: false` property to all columns which you don't want to show in View dialog.

You added only `sortable: false` as property to `Action` column. I would recommend you to include some other properties to the column where you use `formatter: "actions"`:

```js
frozen: true,
fixed: true,
resizable: false,
sortable: false,
search: false,
editable: false,
viewable: false
```

I define typically the column template (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6047856/315935) for example) for `formatter: "actions"`. I include all the above properties (and some other settings like default `width`, `formatoptions: { keys: true }` and other) which I use typically. In the way the code of the grid will be smaller and better readable.

Comment: Awesome once again... Take a bow.. @Oleg