# Multiple jqGrid on the same page with filterToolbar option for date fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am having some trouble with getting 2 jqGrids working on the same page. Each of these grid contains a Date Field with the **exact** same name.

I have configured the `filterToolbar` option using jquery datepicker. After selecting a date from the **second** grid, the value gets populated back to the first grid.

Here's the jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/g2oo5nhc/8/

I think this might be an ID collision problem. Is this a bug? Or is there something wrong with my set up?

If this is indeed a bug, is there any workarounds for this problem?

Comment: This is happening because two of the search elements have the same value `gs_date` for both the search fields in the grid. So datepicker tried to find the first element with that id and puts the value in that search box. You need to add idPrefix dynamically in one of your grids. I am looking into how it can be done and I will post an answer when I find something.

Comment: Look at [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29049120/315935). It's important to know which version of jqGrid you use and which *real code* you use. The demo is very dirty and I don't think the you really use jqGrid in the way. Which `datatype` you use in the real code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jqGrid - datepicker fail on multiple grids when same column name is used is each grid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041985/jqgrid-datepicker-fail-on-multiple-grids-when-same-column-name-is-used-is-each)

Comment: @Oleg, you are right. Using `jsonmap` will resolve the issue.