# How to reuse jqGrid options

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have seen several post regarding this question. But not get the actual answer I want.

I know that I can set a global setting for all of my jqGrids in the application. Then I don't need to mention those options in the newly created jqGrids.

But I want to set some module specific option settings. Suppose I want to use jqGrid for my sales module. I have also set some option as a global option for all of my jqGrids. Now for sales module I want that each sales jqGrid will share some common options. But any sales grid can override one or two option from the common option. How can I do that.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29659748/put-jqgrid-properties-in-a-common-variable-and-reuse-them

Comment: Might be. But here Oleg has explained it more clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really easy to do. You should just understand that the code for creating jqGrid look like

```
$("#gridid").jqGrid(objectWithGridOptions);
```

One use mostly anonymous inline object initialization like

```
$("#gridid").jqGrid({
    // ... some options
});
```

but it do nothing more as

```
var objectWithGridOptions = {
    // ... some options
};
$("#gridid").jqGrid(objectWithGridOptions);
```

So if you want to create multiple grids

```
$("#gridid1").jqGrid({
    // ... some common options
    // ... some options specific for grid 1
});
$("#gridid2").jqGrid({
    // ... some common options
    // ... some options specific for grid 2
});
$("#gridid3").jqGrid({
    // ... some common options
    // ... some options specific for grid 3
});
```

then you can define the object with common options and extend it using [$.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) to the specific object for the grid. In the way you can even overwrite some common options. So if you use some option in grid 1 and grid 2, but not in grid 3 you can still include the most common option in the common object and just include the new value during creating of the grid 3.

The code can look like

```
// the part can be in separate js file which you includes
// on all pages of your project
var commonModuleOption = {
        // ... some common options
    };

$("#gridid1").jqGrid($.extend(true, {}, commonModuleOption, {
    // ... some options specific for grid 1
});
$("#gridid2").jqGrid($.extend(true, {}, commonModuleOption, {
    // ... some options specific for grid 2
});
$("#gridid3").jqGrid($.extend(true, {}, commonModuleOption, {
    // ... some options specific for grid 3
});
```

Comment: You are always a life saver.

Answer (score 1):

if you are able to use `PHP` or a similar serverside language, this is easy to achieve:

```
$("#my_grid").jqGrid({
    <?php
        include "global_jqGrid_options.js";
        include "sales_jqGrid_options.js";
    ?>
});
```

your options-files look like this for example:

```
height: 575,        
autowidth: true,
shrinkToFit: true
```

options from the second include file should override concurring options from the first (but i haven't tested this).

Comment: Well. But can't I keep them in js file and use from there ?

Comment: @Jimcarry not sure if i am understanding. but why would you want to keep global options in the same js file as your jqGrid? or do you really want to have one single js - file for everything?