# How to make the "jqGrid toolbar search" search for the at in any occurrence, not just the beginning

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I've implemented a jqGrid with a toolbar search enabled on it.
The problem is that the search is working like '%search_criteria' (only matching from the beginning)
but I need it to be like '%search_criteria%' (any occurrence in the column value).

e.g: The Grid has a column "Class" with values: Math-101, and Math-102
If searched for: "101" ==> get zero matches.
I have to search for the whole word "Math-101".

I saw an example which working as I wont, and its not different from my Grid at all, and I don't how its working on the example below and not on mine!!!
Ex: http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithSearchingToolbar.htm

My Grid:

```js
var data = [[1, "Math-101", "OC", "INTEL", "09-02-15", "09-30-15", "A", 120, "General", 200]]
$("#grid").jqGrid({
                    datatype: "local",
                    height: 200,
                    colNames:['#','Class','Loc','Type','Start Dt','End Dt','Section','Dur','Gen/Priv','Fee'],
                    colModel: [
                    {name: 'scheduleID',    index: 'scheduleID',  width: 30},
                    {name: 'className',     index: 'className',   width: 60},
                    {name: 'Location',      index: 'Location',    width: 60},
                    {name: 'classType',     index: 'classType',   width: 60},
                    {name: 'startDt',       index: 'startDt',     width: 60,  sorttype: "date",
                    searchoptions:{dataInit:function(el){$(el).datepicker({dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'});} }},
                    {name: 'endDt',         index: 'endDt',       width: 60,  sorttype: "date",
                    searchoptions:{dataInit:function(el){$(el).datepicker({dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'});} }},
                    {name: 'section',       index: 'section',     width: 60},
                    {name: 'duration',      index: 'duration',    width: 60},
                    {name: 'scheduleType',  index: 'scheduleType',width: 60},
                    {name: 'Fee',           index: 'Fee',         width: 60, formatter:'number', align:'right'}
                    ],
                    pager: '#pager',
                    rowNum: 10,
                    rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                    rownumbers: true,
                    sortname: "Class",
                    sortorder: "desc",
                    viewrecords: true,
                    gridview: true,
                    ignoreCase: true,
                    autoencode: true,
                    autowidth: true,
                    ExpandColClick: true,
                    caption: "Schedule List"
            });
                    var names = ['scheduleID', 'className', 'Location', 'classType', 'startDt', 'endDt', 'Section', 'duration', 'scheduleType', 'Fee', 'CEU', 'Status', 'IFee', 'TCost', 'FCost', 'MCost', 'OMCost'];
                    var mydata = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            mydata[i] = {};
                    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
            mydata[i][names[j]] = data[i][j];
            }
            }

            for (var i = 0; i <= mydata.length; i++) {
            $("#grid").jqGrid('addRowData', i + 1, mydata[i]);
            }

            
        $("#grid").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOperators: false, searchOnEnter: false, autosearch: true, defaulySearch: "cn" });
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace `defaulySearch: "cn"` to `defaultSearch: "cn"`. It should fix the main searching problem. You should consider to use `ignoreCase: true` option of jqGrid to force jqGrid uses case insensitive searching.

Additionally I would strictly recommend you don't use `addRowData` in the loop for filling of jqGrid. Instead of that you should just move the code which fill the grid data `mydata` *before* creating the grid and to use just the option `data: mydata`. It will create the data with filled data. The first page to the sorted data will be displayed. jqGrid will sort the data before it will be displayed.

Small additional remarks: you should fix `sortname: "Class"` to `sortname: "className"`. I would recommend you to remove all `index` values from `colModel`. You can consider to use `cmTemplate: { width: 60 }` option (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6047856/315935)) which changes the default value of the property `width` in `colModel` from 150 to 60. After that you can remove all `width: 60` from `colModel`. I recommend you to add `sorttype: 'number'` to the column which uses `formatter:'number'`. It will fix sorting in the column. You can consider to define `template` for two columns which contains dates (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6047856/315935)).

Comment: OMG!!! I can't believe that this was the problem :( I wasted many hours changing and adding useless option like the index and etc...

Comment: Thanks for the help, and also for the additional tips. This the first jqGrid I create. I'm creating a simple application on my own to implement JQuery UI, Json, and restful services. So please If you have a blog or something like that for the best jqGrid implementation, with more of these tip, it would be very useful. Thanks

Comment: @MohammadKhalawi: You are welcome! I develop my own fork of jqGrid: [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) which is based on jqGrid 4.7 and which can be used under MIT/GPL-licences like before (see readme). I posted some articles in [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki) and plan to post soon more information about jqGrid/free jqGrid [here](http://free-jqgrid.github.io/) (it's empty currently).