# How to add button with icon inside jqGrid Formatter

Tags: jquery, html, jqgrid

I tried to add a button inside a jqGrid column, with an icon – but it is coming as `undefined`. What is the correct way to do this?

[image]

CODE

```
colModel: [
    { name: 'RoleID', index: 'RoleID', width: 100 },
    { name: 'RoleName', index: 'RoleName', width: 250 },
    { name: 'RoleRequestedDate', index: 'RoleRequestedDate', formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'm/d/Y', newformat: 'm/d/Y' }, width: 125 },
    { name: 'RoleApprovedDate', index: 'RoleApprovedDate', formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'm/d/Y', newformat: 'm/d/Y' }, width: 125 },

    {
        name: 'Request', index: 'RoleID', width: 120,
        formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
            //return '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-plus app-custom-button-create"  title="Create";"></span>';
            if (rowObject["UserRoleID"] == "0") {
                if (rowObject["RoleRequestID"] == "0") {
                    //return '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-plus app-custom-button-request"  title="Request";"></span>';
                    //return '<button id="btnRequest" class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-plus app-custom-button-request"  type="submit" return false;>Request</button>';

                    return 
                            '<button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default">' +
                            '<span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-star">Request</span>' +
                            '</button>';

                }
                else {
                    return '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-folder-collapsed"  title="Already Requested";"></span>';
                }

            }
            else {
                return '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-check"  title="Has Role";"></span>';
            }
        }
    }

],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that your main computer language is C# and you try to use JavaScript in the same style like you write your C# program. It's an important error! You create in the way the code which looks correct, but it works in the wrong way. I developed many years before the code in C/C++/C# and many other non-C-like languages. So I did the same errors like you. Only after understanding that JavaScript have *absolutely another semantic* I changed my style *for JavaScript programs* and all become good.

Back to your code. You wrote the statement

```js
return 
    '<button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default">' +
    '<span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-star">Request</span>' +
    '</button>';
```

which looks correctly, and it would be correctly in C#, but it will be interpreted as the following in JavaScript:

```js
return;
'<button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default">' +
'<span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-star">Request</span>' +
'</button>';
```

So you have **two statements** because of auto-inserting of semicolon. The first line return `undefined` and the second like will be never executed at all and it will be removed it you would minimize your JavaScript code.

I strictly recommend you to use the following simple rule: if you need to continue the statement on another line you should end the line with the part of the symbol like `+` or `{` or any other which can't be as the last symbol of the statement. You should not know exactly all rules of auto-inserting of semicolon. The rules will be never works in the case at all.

In your case you need just write

```js
return '<button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default">' +
    '<span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-star">Request</span>' +
    '</button>';
```

By the way I personally prefer to use `"` in strings and use `'` inside of string. The rule is a little better because the same rule hold the most JavaScript frameworks/libraries.

The next example from your code: you use the line

```js
if (rowObject["UserRoleID"] == "0") {
    ...
```

The main problem here is the usage of **equality operator** `==`, typical for C#, instead of **strict equality operator** `===` which is strictly recommended to use in JavaScript. The problem is that the code which use `==` looks not like it do in reality. JavaScript uses **type conversion** in case of `==` usage which can produce very strange effects. For example `0 == "0"` is `true` and `false == "0"` is true. It's not what one want in the most cases. The classical example which shows how dangerous is the operator `==`: `0 == ''` is `true` and `0 == '0'` is `true`, but `'' == '0'` is of cause `false`. So the usage of `==` can easy break the main mathematical rules.

More simple and non-critical changes which I recommend you to do is the usage of `rowObject.UserRoleID` instead of `rowObject["UserRoleID"]`. You should use `["..."]` syntax only with variables or if you use the properties which contains either special characters like `rowObject["User.Role.ID"]` or `rowObject["User Role ID"]` or it the property name is reserved word in some JavaScript dialect like `rowObject["class"]` or `rowObject["if"]`.

The next remark: you should verify the quotes (`"`) in the strings `'... title="Has Role";"></span>'` and `'... title="Already Requested";"></span>';`. The part `;"` should be probebly removed.

Finally, small remarks specific for jqGrid. First of all I recommend you to remove unneeded `index` property from `colModel`. You will have the same results after removing of `index`, but your code will be shorter and easy to read. The next advice: you should consider to add `key: true` to the column `RoleID` if it contains *unique* values. It informs jqGrid to use the values as rowids (the values for `id` attribute of `<tr>` elements).

The last remark: you should  confider to use column templates. In simplest form you can define the object

```js
var myDateTemplate = { formatter: 'date',
        formatoptions: { srcformat: 'm/d/Y', newformat: 'm/d/Y' }, width: 125 };
```

somewhere above the code which creates jqGrid and to define `RoleRequestedDate` and `RoleApprovedDate` as the following

```
{ name: 'RoleRequestedDate', template: myDateTemplate },
{ name: 'RoleApprovedDate', template: myDateTemplate },
```

It reduces your code, makes it more readable and easy to maintain. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6047856/315935) or [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/pull/631) for more information about column templates.