# Struts 2 jquery grid default column template

Tags: jquery, struts2, jqgrid, struts2-jquery-plugin, struts2-jquery-grid

The jGrid supports the column templates. Which can be used as the default template for all columns. Some explanation is at [Stopping columns resizable in jqgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044047/stopping-columns-resizable-in-jqgrid)

An the sample code from there:

```
var myDateTemplate = {sorttype:'date', formatter:'date',
                      formatoptions: {newformat:'m/d/Y'}, datefmt: 'm/d/Y',
                      align:'center', width:80 }
$("list").jqGrid({
    colModel: [
        ...
        {name:'column1': template:myDateTemplate},
        {name:'column2': template:myDateTemplate, width:90},
        ...
    ]
    ...
});
```

Is it possible that we use this feature while we are using jquery grid tags `sjg:grid` and `sjg:gridColumn` ? How?

Comment: Struts2 uses some JavaScript version of jqGrid, included directly. Which version of jqGrid you use now and from which fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? If you use old one than I think all will works exactly in the same way if you replace `jquery.jqgrid.min.js`, .... to new version. The problem is: the last versions of jqGrid supports **string** value for `template`. I think that it makes easy the usage of `sjg:gridColumn`. Do you have some demo which shows how you use jqGrid?

Comment: You can find a live demo and code samples at http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action Please select widgets and then grid. I have use it the same why which mentioned there. If you need more info please let me know.  It uses jqGrid verison 4.6.0 You can find it at (http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/struts/js/plugins/jquery.jqGrid.js?s2j=3.7.1). Thanks!

Comment: I don't use Struts2 or Java myself, but the code from https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery/tree/master/struts2-jquery-grid-plugin/src/main seems be the last one. It contains the JavaScript code of jqGrid and simple wrapper structures for every property. Like [here](https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery/blob/master/struts2-jquery-grid-plugin/src/main/java/com/jgeppert/struts2/jquery/grid/components/GridColumn.java), ...

Comment: [here](https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery/blob/master/struts2-jquery-grid-plugin/src/main/java/com/jgeppert/struts2/jquery/grid/views/jsp/ui/GridColumnTag.java). [Here](https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery/tree/master/struts2-jquery-grid-plugin/src/main/resources/template) are original jqGrid JavaScript files. It seems that you can replace the JavaScript files to [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) files and make minimal changes of the code or wrapper classes to use new functionality.