# Date format wrong on save

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I need a little help, I have created a grid that works well for the most part except when I edit the row and click save; the order date changes dramatically and I don't see the pattern to figure out how to fix it. I have changed the `srcformat` and `newformat` parameters, I have also tried a whole slew of different things all of which don't seem to work. Can someone take a look at my fiddle and tell me what is going on with that date?

In order to test the fiddle please choose a row and then click edit (pencil icon) then enter a 4 for quantity and some gibberish in the reason field, click save, look at the order date, it changes from the default to some random date. I am using the latest verion of free-jqgrid (4.12.1)

https://jsfiddle.net/y3llowjack3t/8zs1q7Lm/1/

```
{
    name: 'OrderDate', index: 'OrderDate', width: 90, align: "center",
    search: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'bw', 'bn', 'cn', 'nc', 'ew', 'en'] },
    formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'm/d/Y' },
    editable: true, editrules: { required: true, date: true },
    editoptions: { dataInit: function (elem) { $(elem).datepicker(); } }
},
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your date/time format. Looks like jqGrig is expecting `2016-04-01T00:00:00` and you are passing back `01/04/2016`.

Modify `aftersavefunc` to include:

```
aftersavefunc: function(iRow, response, options) {

  // ...
  currentRowData.OrderDate = moment(currentRowData.OrderDate).format();
  // ...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem in your code is **not in the date** column, but in the `aftersavefunc` function which you use. If you just comment the callback function you will see that free jqGrid correctly saves the data: https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/8zs1q7Lm/3/.

I would suggest you to make some changes in your current code. First of all you should fix the rowids. The `RecurringOrderId` property of input data seems be unique. It's a good choice for rowid values. You should add `localReader: { id: "RecurringOrderId" }` because you use `datatype: "local"`.

After the changes you will not need to used the code fragments like

```
var rowData = $('#editFrequencyTable').getRowData(val);
efData = $.grep(efData, function(value, i) {
    return value.RecurringOrderId !== rowData.RecurringOrderId;
});
```

to get the data by rowid. Instead of that rowid from all callbacks will be already the `RecurringOrderId` value and you can use `$('#editFrequencyTable').getLocalRow(rowid)` to get the data by rowid. The method `getLocalRow` is much quickly as `getRowData` and it get **all properties** of original item. Thus you don't need to use any hidden columns. You can just remove the columns (`RecurringOrderId`, `PONumber` and `Edited`) from `colModel` and will have still the properties accessible.

Some other options can be just removed `loadonce: true`, `height: 'auto'`, `datatype: "local"`, not existing `gridView: true` (`gridview: true` would be correct, but it's default in free jqGrid). In the same way you can remove unneeded `index` property from all `colModel` items and `search: true`.

You can use `navOptions`, `inlineNavOptions`, `searching`, `formDeleting`, `inlineEditing` options of jqGrid to make the code more readable. See [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/New-style-of-usage-options-of-internal-methods) for details. As the result you get the code like

https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/8zs1q7Lm/4/

It's clear that you can clean up the code and reduce it much more. After the usage of correct rowid and `getLocalRow` you would can easy access and modify the data. I think that you can do this yourself. You can reduce the code of `colModel` additionally by usage of column templates. See [the old article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6047856/315935) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for the descriptive response.