# jqGrid Grouping only showing results from current page

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid for the first time this week, looking to update an existing website that uses DataTables.

Everything is working well except for when I look at Grouping attributes. The Grouped results are only using the data for the current page, not all pages in the table.

How do I make it so that Grouping by a field shows all Group Values and not just the values from the current page?

I'm using a json source file.

<strike>I tried making the code example work in the below Fiddle, but I have not done this before and couldn't get it to work with an external json file stored as a public dropbox link.</strike>
Thanks to @oleg, I have the fiddle example working which demonstrates the problem, and the code has also been cleaned up making use of column templates and the free version of jqGrid.

```js
$(function() {
  "use strict";
  $.jgrid.defaults.guiStyle = "bootstrap";
  $.jgrid.defaults.iconSet = "fontAwesome";
  var template1 = {
    "groupOp": "AND",
    "rules": [{
      "field": "CustomerID",
      "op": "bw",
      "data": "W"
    }, {
      "field": "Freight",
      "op": "le",
      "data": "15"
    }]
  };

  var template2 = {
    "groupOp": "AND",
    "rules": [{
      "field": "e",
      "op": "bw",
      "data": "SEGU"
    }, {
      "field": "i",
      "op": "eq",
      "data": "2200"
    }]
  };

  $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
      url: 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/nh7rcwcimxljjr2/data.json',
      datatype: "json",
      cmTemplate: {
        align: "center",
        searchoptions: {
          searchOperMenu: true,
          sopt: ["bw", "ge", "le", "eq", "ne", "lt", "gt", "bn", "in", "ni", "ew", "en", "cn", "nc"]
        }
      },
      colModel: [{
        label: 'Position',
        name: 'p',
        width: 100
      }, {
        label: 'Equipment Nbr',
        key: true, // ??? only if e is unique in the input data
        name: 'e'
      }, {
        label: 'Length',
        name: 'l',
        width: 95
      }, {
        label: 'Height',
        name: 'ch',
        width: 90
      }, {
        label: 'ISO Code',
        name: 'i',
        width: 110
      }, {
        label: 'Carrier',
        name: 'c',
        width: 95
      }, {
        label: 'Bay',
        name: 'ba',
        width: 75
      }, {
        label: 'Row',
        name: 'ro',
        width: 75
      }, {
        label: 'Tier',
        name: 'ti',
        width: 75
      }, {
        label: 'Type',
        name: 'ty',
        width: 90
      }, {
        label: 'Status',
        name: 's',
        width: 90
      }, {
        label: 'Bundle?',
        name: 'b',
        width: 100
      }, {
        label: 'Attached Nbr',
        name: 'a',
      }, {
        label: 'Pos Format',
        name: 'pf',
        width: 125
      }, {
        label: 'VGM',
        name: 'wv',
        width: 100
      }, {
        label: 'Weight',
        name: 'w',
        width: 100
      }, {
        label: 'OOG',
        name: 'o',
        width: 75
      }, {
        label: 'Dimensions',
        name: 'dn',
        width: 200
      }, {
        label: 'Hazardous',
        name: 'hz',
        width: 120
      }, {
        label: 'IMDG Code',
        name: 'im',
        width: 125
      }, {
        label: 'UN Number',
        name: 'un',
        width: 125
      }, {
        label: 'Reefer',
        name: 'r',
        width: 90
      }, {
        label: 'Temp',
        name: 'tp',
      }, {
        label: 'Range',
        name: 'ra',
        width: 130
      }, {
        label: 'Description',
        name: 'd',
        width: 125
      }, {
        label: 'Handling',
        name: 'h',
        width: 125
      }, {
        label: 'Load Remarks',
        name: 'lr',
        width: 140
      }, {
        label: 'POL',
        name: 'pl',
        width: 80
      }, {
        label: 'POD',
        name: 'pd',
        width: 80
      }, {
        label: 'Optional POD',
        name: 'op',
        width: 140
      }, {
        label: 'Destination',
        name: 'de',
        width: 125
      }, {
        label: '1st POD',
        name: 'p1',
        width: 110
      }, {
        label: '2nd POD',
        name: 'p2',
        width: 110
      }, {
        label: '3rd POD',
        name: 'p3',
        width: 110
      }, {
        label: '4th POD',
        name: 'p4',
        width: 110
      }, {
        label: '5th POD',
        name: 'p5',
        width: 110
      }, {
        label: 'Transhipment Port',
        name: 'pt',
        width: 175
      }, {
        label: 'Next POD',
        name: 'np',
        width: 115
      }, {
        label: 'Ref Code',
        name: 'rc',
        width: 110
      }, {
        label: 'Ref',
        name: 'ref',
        width: 80
      }],
      viewrecords: true,
      autowidth: true,
      sortable: true,
      height: 400,
      rowNum: 17,
      shrinkToFit: false,
      loadonce: true,
      sortname: 'c',
      hoverrows: true,
      rownumbers: true,
      multiselect: true,
      multiPageSelection: true,
      pager: true,
      groupingView: {
        groupOrder: ["desc"],
        groupText: ["<b>{0}</b> - {1} record(s) found"],
        groupColumnShow: [true],
        groupCollapse: true
      },
      searching: {
        stringResult: true,
        searchOperators: true,
        multipleSearch: true,
        caption: "Advanced Query Builder",
        Find: " Filter",
        Reset: " Reset",
        multipleGroup: true,
        showQuery: true,
        //tmplNames: ["Template One", "SEGU 2200"],
        //tmplFilters: [template1, template2]
      }
    }).jqGrid('filterToolbar')
    .jqGrid("navGrid", {
      add: false,
      edit: false,
      del: false
    });

  $("#dynamicGrouping").change(function() {
    var groupingName = $(this).val();
    if (groupingName) {
      $("#jqGrid").jqGrid("setGridParam", {
          rowNum: 250
        })
        .jqGrid('groupingGroupBy', groupingName);
    } else {
      $("#jqGrid").jqGrid("setGridParam", {
          rowNum: 25
        })
        .jqGrid('groupingRemove');
    }
  });
  $("#getSelectedRows").click(function() {
    var selectedIDs = $("#jqGrid").getGridParam("selarrrow");
    alert(selectedIDs.length === 0 ? "No rows are selected" : selectedIDs.join());
  });
});
```

```css
a.soptclass {
  border: 2px;
}
th {
  background-color: #aaa;
}
.two-col {
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Makes this div contain its floats */
}
.two-col .col1,
.two-col .col2 {
  width 49%;
}
.two-col .col1 {
  float: left;
}
.two-col .col2 {
  float: right;
}
.two-col label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.13.5/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.13.5/js/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div style="margin-left:20px; margin-right:20px;">

  <div class="two-col">
    <div class="col1">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="dynamicGrouping">Group Data By:</label>
        <select id="dynamicGrouping" class="form-control" style="width:auto;">
          <option value="">No Grouping</option>
          <option value="c">Carrier</option>
          <option value="l">Length</option>
          <option value="h">Height</option>
          <option value="i">ISO Code</option>
          <option value="ba">Bay</option>
          <option value="s">Status</option>
          <option value="o">Is OOG?</option>
          <option value="hz">Is Hazardous?</option>
          <option value="r">Is Reefer?</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <table id="jqGrid"></table>
  <br>
  <input id="getSelectedRows" class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Get Selected Rows" />
</div>
```

Comment: You can load the JSON data in JSFiddle demo using the URL https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/nh7rcwcimxljjr2/data.json. I'd strictly recommend you to use column template to reduce your code and make it more readable and maintainable (see [the old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6047856/315935)). You use **commercial** Guriddo jqGrid JS (see [the prices](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334)), but there are exist another fork [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) too (see [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html)): https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/5prjcgte/1/

Comment: @Oleg - I see that this section of code almost fixes the problem

`$("#dynamicGrouping").change(function() {
        var groupingName = $(this).val();
        if (groupingName) {
            $("#jqGrid").jqGrid("setGridParam", {rowNum: 9999})
             .jqGrid('groupingGroupBy', groupingName);
        } else {
            $("#jqGrid").jqGrid("setGridParam", {rowNum: 250})
             .jqGrid('groupingRemove');
        }
    });`

But when the Grouping is removed, rowNum remains at 9999 instead of going back down to 250, so this makes the table slow

Comment: @Oleg - I have fixed this issue by triggering reloadGrid when removing the grouping.

`$("#dynamicGrouping").change(function() {
        var groupingName = $(this).val();
        if (groupingName) {
            $("#jqGrid").jqGrid("setGridParam", {rowNum: 9999})
             .jqGrid('groupingGroupBy', groupingName);
        } else {
            $("#jqGrid").jqGrid("setGridParam", {rowNum: 250})
             .jqGrid('groupingRemove');
             $('#jqGrid').trigger( 'reloadGrid' );
        }
    });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function makes the grouping work the way I need.

```js
$("#dynamicGrouping").change(function() {
        var groupingName = $(this).val();
        if (groupingName) {
            $("#jqGrid").jqGrid("setGridParam", {rowNum: 9999})
             .jqGrid('groupingGroupBy', groupingName);
        } else {
            $("#jqGrid").jqGrid("setGridParam", {rowNum: 250})
             .jqGrid('groupingRemove');
             $('#jqGrid').trigger( 'reloadGrid' );
        }
    });
```